# Can I flag posts from SEDE or a search in bulk if they're low quality?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I recently had a couple NAA flags declined on some link-only answers (they really were, but I don't really want to make this about a few cases unless *really* necessary) with:

> declined - Please don't flag posts based on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) queries.

Which is exactly what I was doing (well, from a search, but it's essentially the same. [This search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A..0+%22link+will%22), to be exact. I'd hand-validate each post before flagging, and got some gems like (10k): [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704939/dropdown-box-index-issue/708535#708535), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110098/hyperlink-or-picture-column-in-sharepoint/6110121#6110121), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011404/publish-a-message-with-hashtag-using-facebook-url-redirect/18053937#18053937))

I'm curious about this. Is it policy? Should it be? What can I do in the future to avoid this (while having the posts taken care of in some way, if possible)?

Comment: To answer your final question, _"What can I do in the future to avoid this?"_, the obvious answer is "don't do what you were doing"; the rest, meh. You were possibly correct, but I can see how NAA flags on 3 year old posts might get annoying, however valid.

Comment: related: [Hide “not an answer” and “very low quality” flags in the moderator flag queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243145/165773) (if only LQ reviewers were given a better chance to handle these flags...)

Answer (score 32):

You didn't flag them as 'very low quality', you flagged them as 'not an answer', but that's tangential.

Among the issues with your flags is that you were literally flagging posts that were years old.

You flagged 35 posts in the span of 5 minutes; with most of those flags mere seconds apart.  4 were declined to get your attention to stop;  So having a 31/35 accept rate isn't bad.

If you didn't use an SEDE query or a google search to generate these flags, I apologize -- but from the moderator console you were rapidly filling up our queue by posts that all had the same format:

> I hope this helps you `<link>`

The reason we say not to use SEDE to auto-flag posts is three-fold:

1. Flagging old posts  is secondary to fixing the current problems on the site. We get thousands of questions a day, that's where we need your help.
2. If there are a lot of posts that exhibit certain characteristics, you should raise a meta question and ask for a feature to be implemented so that these posts can be nipped in the bud automatically.
3. There are a lot of flags in the moderator queue at any given time; you got lucky in that we had just cleared the queue. You were also unlucky in that we had just cleared the queue an it was really apparent you were using some sort of tool to find these problem posts.

We prefer that you flag organically. If you don't want to do that, then make it easier on all of us and ask to have the software improved through a programmatic means where you're not asking Moderators to intervene in years old answers just because 'they should be cleaned up'.

Comment: In addition to the above, it's also our experience that SEDE queries tend to get abused for flagging items. A few responsible users will run these queries, read each of the items that come up, and flag the ones that really need our attention. Others then use these queries and start blindly flagging everything that comes up, which ends up wasting a lot of time and burying the signal in piles of noise.

Comment: The recent anti-plagiarism queries were a good example of these done right: people read the posts, identified the material they were copied from, and we were able to process those rapidly. On the flip side, another group started running queries for answers under a certain length and flagged every one of those that came up as "very low quality", no matter if they were good answers or not. That was less helpful.

Comment: I'm all for you flagging with the help of SEDE queries. But 35 NAA flags within 5 minutes seems to be a little overkill. Not saying you weren't doing this, but always make sure to read the question and answer. Lots of questions ask for a link only, so it's best just to close the question rather than delete an answer that was asked for.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, and mod team for processing the plagiarism flags so fast despite the volume of flags.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi We don't encourage it because with our volume, we seldom have less than hundreds of flags in the queue. We have enough of a backlog and enough daily traffic that it's a full time job just to keep up with what's coming in, let alone the old stuff.

Comment: I disagree with #1 as a generalized point. This is a long-term knowledge base. Particularly on high-score/view-count posts, the impact of things that should be flagged is worth multiple-times the impact of the average of each and every new _single_ thing that comes up every day.

Comment: Point #2 does not seem to have aged very well. I do not see recent cases of old, fairly simple high-impact, proposals for automatic prevention of flag-worthy things getting dev time or even company attention. Ex. [Automatically recognize and remove "thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169858/997587). I made one such proposal myself: [Make short "saved my <time>" comments single-flag-deletable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386115/997587) and went and did the legwork of the SEDE analysis. silence.

Comment: I also find it irksome that the things I spend all my 100 post flags on _as they pop up every day_ (I.e. _new flagworthy things_) are easily toolable, such as new non-answers on old question. [Dharman has a bot](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210133/naabot), and there's also [Natty](//chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/126814). Why isn't the _system_ doing things about this? These are not new problems, nor are they problems that are difficult to get sizable positive changes on. If the problem is that the flags are too much for the mods alone, then that's a solvable problem too.

Answer (score 21):

Consider two scenarios:

1. You are walking down the street and see a dead cat in the gutter.
2. You are blazing a new trail in a remote part of a city park and see a dead cat under an overhang.

Under which scenario are you most likely to call your local Bureau of Sanitation for dead animal collection?

Flagging is a bit like calling your city's [waste disposal service](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). The idea is to clean up eyesores before they cause problems. An answer that you stumble upon while using the site is *very likely* to be noticed by others. But using some sort of search to turn up non-answers is likely to be looking for problems that might never be noticed.

I can see the argument that trash is trash and we should clean it up even if it never causes problems. But it's not always clear what should be done about link-only answers. For instance, your query turns up answers (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224956/add-link-in-magento-menu/10226645#10226645)) that seem to be useful. Sure it's a link to another page that might not exist in the future and the OP couldn't make it work, but the answer and comments are breadcrumbs that just might help someone else with the same problem. Maybe it should be converted to a comment. Maybe it should be edited into shape. Maybe the answer is wrong and needs to be downvoted. Maybe it's really spam and should be deleted. By flagging an answer like this, you are asking someone else to make that judgement call for you.

Diamond moderators have been entrusted with a great deal of authority to make difficult decisions. On Stack Overflow, it's not uncommon to see individual moderators handle hundreds of flags in a week. (This past week one broke 1,000 and another 2,500!) Each of those decisions take a little bit of time and [a little bit of mental energy](http://www.economist.com/node/18557594) to make. So unless you are finding really obvious problems of the discount-handbag-spam variety, flagging old posts probably isn't worth the total effort expended. By using up a finite resource (moderator time) you might be actively harming the site as a whole.

Comment: Sounds like a convincing argument to channel those flags to a Low Quality Review Queue instead of moderators.

Comment: discount-handbag-post links can be posted in the tavern too, so that the burden of nuking spam is shared by the community members. Tavern nukes some spam posts once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I flag posts from SEDE or a search in bulk if they're low quality?

Answers rarely fit the *low quality* flag. However, many answers **do fit** the *Not An Answer* flag.. which in turn sends most of those flags to the Low Quality Queue.

So, yes, you can use SEDE to search for answers that are *Not An Answer*. Please read and ***understand*** Shog9's official post on when [an answer is not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), before ever using SEDE to search for *Not an Answer* posts. The last thing we want is many bad answers which are in fact answers, ending up in that queue and being mistakenly deleted by robo-reviewers.

Use SEDE as a tool to help find the *Not An Answer* posts. Don't use it as the only means to determine if something is *Not An Answer*. Make sure to read the question. Make sure to read the answer. If your not sure, either re-read them and then make your decision, or just let it be and don't flag.

---

Honestly though, there have been so many answers deleted for *Not An Answer* within the last few months, that I think we already got most of them. So I'd stick with searching for only newer answers, like within the last month or so.

---

Some/most mods are against using SEDE queries for clean ups like this for reasons already stated in their answers here. I can definitely see their points, but I don't agree that responsible users shouldn't use the SEDE for this. The fact is that Stack Overflow is moderated by the community. Not just mods. Most of these *NAA* flags don't have to involve a mod and use up their time. Most can be handled without them anyways.

I have noticed that maybe the workload in the SO mod queues is becoming too much too often. So maybe it would be good to have another election sometime soon to lighten the work load for each individual mod?

Comment: I don't agree with the "have elections and get more mods" part.