# Should moderators run automated bots under their accounts?

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges, moderators, comment-flags

The most recent [Stack Overflow election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354232/2017-community-moderator-election-results) brought up some great new moderators, including Andy, who has for the past [~3 years been running a comment flag bot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically) to automatically flag comments for removal. Since the end of the election, Andy graciously turned off the bot until we determined how best to proceed with it possibly running under his account.

During the time the bot was running, it flagged approximately 109,772 comments. Of these:

- 109,494 were marked helpful, and
- 278 were declined

That means the bot was **accurate ~99% of the time**.

Now that Andy is a moderator on the site, there are a few things that need to be discussed and decided before turning it back on:

1. Should it run under his main account, with mod privileges?
2. Should it run under another account, one which is controlled by Andy but without mod privileges attached?

Before chiming in on these, here are some things to think about:

- If the bot is run under his main account, then it would have the same privileges that he has as a moderator. This means there would no longer be a limit to the number of comments that could be deleted per day - the normal 100 flags per day limit would not be in effect. The bot could continue to delete comments without restrictions.
- If we do decide to let the comment-flagging bot run under a moderator account, it also means there will no longer be a pair of human eyes on the comment to make the final decision about deletion. A flag raised by the bot will auto-delete the comment and not send it to the mod queue for additional review.
- Like any other decision made by a moderator, everything is logged and tracked in the database, so if the bot deletes thousands of comment we have record of everything it does.
- Finally, if the bot is run under a moderator account, then any action it takes would fall under the [moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) that Andy signed post-election, meaning his main account would suffer any consequences if we determined that the bot was behaving badly.

With all that in mind, do we think it's appropriate for a moderator to run a bot under their main account to flag/delete comments unilaterally? Or should it be run separately from an account without moderator privileges?

Comment: Could we have some more insights on the declined comment flags? Were those really good/useful comments that were rightfully declined, or more like borderline cases that could have been deleted anyways as well? (Or perhaps misclicks by the moderator handling the flags?). I mean, it would be annoying if 1 good comment get deleted even if 100000 bad ones are also deleted, but if it's 1 borderline comment, that changes the whole perspective in my opinion.

Comment: @g00glen00b Looks like [Andy gave some context in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354723/426671).

Comment: Do moderators have larger access to the API? Andy said that it only returns 10,000 comment results at max, is that cap removed for moderators?

Comment: @TravisJ They do not have a larger access. Everything is the same as before Andy was a mod.

Comment: I have a question about *Like any other decision made by a moderator, everything is logged and tracked in the database, so if the bot deletes thousands of comment we have record of everything it does.*.  Does this mean there will still be some human review, or just if the *stuff* hits the fan we will have a record of what needs to be checked?

Comment: How many of the flags are still sitting in a review queue not final reviewed yet?

Comment: @NathanOliver If things hit the fan, we'd have record of it. There is not human review of it unless we need to look.

Comment: @JasonVanBenschoten At this particular moment, the SO mod flag queue has 25 items waiting for review.

Comment: @bluefeet that makes me feel better tbh! i like the prospect even more now.

Comment: @JasonVanBenschoten I will say that prior to the recent election, we were averaging near 2k flags in the queue. Most of the time I'd say the SO mod queue is around 1k flags.

Comment: If SE API had given more powers to the mods, it'd have been throttled and killed by now @travis. :p .... There are so many potential chances of catching bad users, plagiarists, vandals, voting rings using the API, which would blow up the number of requests.

Comment: Paraphrasing a number of answers, there's some concern about letting a bot go without any oversight, but it sounds like running four copies might catch everything. Is there a reason not to simply increase one of the rate limits or run four sock-bots, rather than go all in and give the bot moderator powers?

Comment: How often do moderators take further action when they delete a comment? Deleting a "Thanks, it worked! :)" comment by a _mod-bot_ is fine, but what about about really abusive comments? Is it possible that the bot will just delete those and move on, while a human moderator may also suspend the commenter?

Comment: @ssube I don't see what problems would be solved by running four bots. Can you clarify that? You can't have the bots supervise each other. Not only because that's like having the inmates run the asylum, but also because all four bots would presumably be based on the same code/algorithm.

Comment: @CodyGray According to [Andy's rough math](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354719/should-moderators-run-automated-bots-under-their-accounts?noredirect=1#comment502170_354722), the bot would flag about 300 items/day but runs against a staggered window. If we had four bots running against 6 hour windows, they might (assuming a constant flow of comments) be able to check everything.

Comment: **Quality** Plain and simple. @Andy created a bot that flagged 109k comments with **99.747% accuracy**. Andy's work has greatly contributed to the overall quality of the site. I think Andy should keep doing what he's been doing. If the community ends up deciding that Andy should run the bot under a separate account then I think all the flag 'kudos'  should be transferred back to Andy's profile after he steps down from his moderator role 3 decades from now.

Comment: Andy has proven that his bot is accurate and effective. I voted for him with the idea in mind that he should ramp up his flagging once he becomes a mod. People are worried about the lack of human oversight - but is it really a problem? The bot is already *way* more accurate than most humans here, and Andy's post below indicates that most of the declined flags were because a *human* made a mistake. I think a few people are against it simply because it's not 'official' - If SO said they were going to integrate this system into their codebase, would people object? Probably not. Then this is fine.

Comment: By requiring Andy to review his bot flags, are we pushing him to make his bot accurate?

Comment: @Ihazkode And the bot's current iteration is even more accurate than that; 99.99% accurate!

Comment: Imo we can't let the bot have mod privs. It's 99% accurate now but if we give it moderator powers there will be no way for us (or Andy) to tell how effective it is going forward and no way for him to further fine tune it in response to circumstances.

Comment: My question is that with an accuracy of ~99%, why isn't SO running this on their own?

Comment: @j08691 As mentioned in a few comments around the post there is a possibility to do that, but resources are elsewhere at this point. Which means it's going to take a while for us to get it in place.

Comment: If I'm frank here, I think what we're going to need is a manifesto for acceptable bot usage on Stack Overflow.  It's no secret that mods use it internally for their own work - a point I don't have an issue with - but in my mind, this issue has transcended, "can we allow this moderator to use a bot?"  Establishing those guidelines are important.  I'll add a new answer to highlight this point so it's not lost in comments.

Comment: @Makoto Are you also going to change your name to Frank? :)

Comment: Create a user Andyroid who is not dimond mod, so that they can be separated?

Comment: I find the conclusion that the bot is reliable pretty questionable.  All we *really* know is that it is good at creating flags that mods often accept.  Flogging something like "Thanks, it works!".  The kind of comment that a mod *must* delete, since not deleting it tends to piss-off the flagger rather a lot.  Given that the mod does not have a choice, it is actually the flagger that makes the judgement call.  And no, such a comment is not automagically unconstructive.  It is the kind of signal that matters in a no-rep asker question.

Comment: Lots of people are saying we elected Andy, not his bot. Lets hold another election so we can elect it.

Comment: Could we do a dry run against the entire comment database and post the results of what would have been deleted and the confidence score for each comment? This would allow us to go through en-masse and review the results large scale.

Comment: @TinyGiant There are 78+ million comments just in SO's database, I'm pretty sure we're not going to run it against all of that.

Comment: @TinyGiant Andy already has the data dump with all the comments, it's available to everyone. You may want to drop by Charcoal HQ to ask him what kind of dry run he could possibly run against that.

Comment: @Michelle I didn't realize that comments were in the data dump. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @bluefeet Was a decision reached? Will this post be updated once this is decided one way or another?

Comment: @TotZam Yes, [and I've posted an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354719/should-moderators-run-automated-bots-under-their-accounts/356509#356509).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reviewing all of the feedback and discussion, the general consensus seems to want to have some human oversight of these flags. As a result, Andy has agreed to run the bot under a separate account allowing the flags to flow into the moderator queue for review.

If the additional flags become a burden for the moderators, then we will revisit this issue at a later date.

Answer (score 154):

No, the bot should not run directly under Andy's account. In other words, the bot should *not* have moderator privileges. Why? One reason:

> If we do decide to let the comment-flagging bot run under a moderator account, it also means there will no longer be a pair of human eyes on the comment to make the final decision about deletion.

The fundamental premise of moderation on Stack Overflow is that it's done by the community—either directly, or by elected representatives. Andy was elected; not his bot. Moreover, I'm extremely uncomfortable with the idea of giving moderator privileges to a bot, no matter how accurate it has statistically been.

If the bot is doing good work, great! Keep it running. But don't remove the human checks.

(I don't see any particular reason to rate-limit the bot, though. If we can find a way to relax rate limits on the bot *without* giving it full moderator privileges, then I would be totally down with that. Perhaps a hack in the short term, and ultimately integrating it into the code base in the long term, [as bluefeet suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354719/should-moderators-run-automated-bots-under-their-accounts#comment502144_354720).)

Comment: I have seen your **excellent** work when I flag one NAA answer, you arrive and clean up the whole Q/A (editing questions, deleting other duplicated answers ecc.). Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45536608/5292302). To me we should not waste a resource like you clicking delete on old *"Thanks works for me"* comments, instead you should concentrate on this kind of work, since it's way more site critical.

Comment: *Just*  to play Devil's Advocate (and I'm doing that a lot lately)...would you be uncomfortable with the Community user having these powers?  So you know where I stand:  I'd be fine with it as again, there's an audit trail and it'd be maintained internally, but I can respect that there are consternations with it.

Comment: Community is quite unlike the typical moderator already, @Makoto. I'm not sure how much I should really reveal, but I think it's safe to say that Community doesn't work like an AI moderator (save for a few specific tasks like the Roomba). There are automatic flags raised by Community, but they are handled by human moderators, which is precisely how I think a comment bot should work. So…no, I would not be uncomfortable with Community having these powers, but I would be uncomfortable with Community becoming sentient and acting like a human moderator.

Comment: I agree, we shouldn't run it under Andy's account... Can I volunteer mine instead?

Comment: Well, I actually voted for his bot…

Comment: For what it's worth, this summarizes my thoughts perfectly. We absolutely should run the bot, but the human check is indispensable, so we absolutely should not run it without supervision (i.e., under Andy's account).

Comment: "The human check is indispensable", I am not so sure, considering that he has more than 99% match, and even the false positive fall more in a grey area than anything. Does our humans have better stats than that ? It has been a long time since you need need human supervision for IA in chess games since it has been proven to be better.

Comment: @Walfrat According to what little bluefeet and Shog revealed in comments, no, it's not likely that our humans have better stats than that.

Comment: Dangit, Cody. You go and win a mod election, and almost immediately you make your first meta post that I am less than completely and vehemently supportive of? You (and several others) mentioned that a human check is important. Could you go into some more detail about why you feel that way? It's not a trick question, there are multiple possible reasons I can imagine (and probably a bunch I haven't thought of), and I'd like to know which one(s) are actually relevant in practice. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) One other thing. (I was thinking about waiting to post this until it could be a follow-up to your reply to my first comment, but that ended up feeling too "trick question"-y.) Technically, running this bot as mod wouldn't take _away_ human checking; it would just shift the check to a more oversight-like "after the fact" process rather than a more active pre-deletion verification. So, let that influence your answer how it will. Not sure how much of this is actually pointing out something new and how much is just semantics.

Comment: @Pops Is it even possible to undelete a comment? I've never heard of it happening.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yep, it is. But only moderators have that option, and only in certain cases can they be undeleted, though I don't quite remember, since I almost never undelete comments :P

Comment: @jpmc26 Moderators can only undelete comments deleted by themselves, community or other moderators.

Comment: @Pops Heh, well it had to happen eventually. :-) Honestly, I'm sure I've put nowhere near as much thought into this as you and the team has. I read your answer, and started wondering if I'm just the luddite that you mentioned. Maybe it's just a gut reaction, since I don't really have a whole lot more depth of justifications to offer, but I'm just fundamentally uncomfortable with removing the human oversight when it comes to deleting other peoples' contributions, *especially* where there is no community oversight (only mods can see deleted comments, unlike answers).

Comment: As far as this not taking away any human checks, well, I agree, and I did consider that, but the issue is, like I mentioned above, the only possible people who can check this are moderators, and the reality is that they *don't*. We don't even check up on other moderators' choices when it comes to deleting comments, so we *certainly* aren't going to regularly check up on a bot. There may be another dimension to this, and that's that I am much less gung-ho about deleting comments than other folks who are vocal on Meta. Deleting noise is fine, but we must be careful not to get too swept up.

Comment: +1 for now; I'm not 100% opposed in principle to automated moderation, but I'm *definitely* opposed to a deletion bot being set loose on the site *without the rest of us having any clear understanding of what stuff it will be removing*. It has a >99% success rate? I don't particularly care, actually; I want to be able to *see* the content that's getting flagged. Right now all that us non-mods have got is an assurance from Andy that *he* can view the flagged content; that's not good enough. If we let this loose now, we do so with zero capacity for community oversight or accountability.

Comment: For what it's worth, I completly agree with cody. The fact that the bot is 99% accurate right now is only possible because Andy was able to fine tune it with feedback of its accuracy. If you give the bot mod privileges, nobody can tell anymore how accurate it is, unless you make a special mod only review queue to second guess the bot's actions, which will amount to about the same situation as without mod privileges.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not just you. The point was that most people are susceptible to this innate bias (and yes, I include myself). Just something to stay cognizant of, I think. Also, there's room for difference of opinion over proportionality. We (as a society) ask for much stricter quality control of the software that keeps planes in the air than the software that runs coffeepots or river quality monitors. Comments on a Q&A site fall somewhere in between, but exactly where is up for debate; therefore, so is the amount we should worry about failures or generally put effort in at all.

Comment: Re not checking on bots because we never check anything, that seems like a separate issue that may need changes, regardless of this bot situation. One more potential concern is conditioning, in that if we do this, it "normalizes" the idea of using bots, which could make people more inclined to propose bots as solutions to other problems in the future, even in situations where they may not be as appropriate or effective as Andy's comment bot.

Comment: @Pops My major concern is that actions taken on behalf of moderators are representative of the site as a whole. I don't think it's a good experience to have your content deleted, at the request of a moderator, because an algorithm was incorrect. Moderators should be exception handlers, not an automated system. Now, it'd be a different question entirely if the bot's detection code was incorporated into SE itself, with an alert to the user at the time of writing the comment. Don't get me wrong; I love the bots the community has developed. They just shouldn't be given moderator powers.

Comment: @Rob got it. I guess I'll mention that when we talked about this internally before bluefeet wrote up the meta question here, I brought up that exact "how do you think people would treat this differently if it were a change to the SE codebase rather than a user running a bot with mod powers" as a thought experiment. But that was for identical code, not a just-in-time remake version.

Comment: @Pops, If it's a JIT notification, the notification should say that the comment will be deleted after the person to whom it's sent sees it, or after some delay, not immediately. A JIT notification will result in people changing what they write so it says basically the same thing, but isn't auto-detected. People who are placing such comments want to express themselves. If you stifle that expression at the time they are posting, they will just find a way around it. As examples, look at the effort we see every day of people working around the auto-detection on question titles, post content, etc.

Answer (score 119):

Allow me to provide a bit more context to the numbers bluefeet has in her post.

Since August 1, 2016 the bot has had 7 declined flags:

- 2 in Sept. 2016
- 2 in Nov. 2016
- 1 in Dec. 2016
- 1 in Jan. 2017
- 1 in Feb. 2017

The bot checks comments from 48 hours ago or older. It will only look at comments that have multiple siblings ([based on this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292012/186281)).

The bot is [responsible for about 15% of the comments flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292060/186281) on Stack Overflow in 2016.

The majority of the declined flags were in the infant stages of the bot. It was also caught in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283030/96-wrongly-declined-comment-flags-in-1-day) shortly after I announced the bot on Meta. Someone attempted to replicate it and wasn't as accurate. This caused moderator grief and I was a side effect. It was shortly after this that I implemented the 48 hour or older rule so that brand new comments weren't being flagged.

Prior to the election the bot flagged 100 comments per day and then was told to stop by the API. It has not run since I was elected.

Declined flags:

1. ["Nope, still show two nav bars. Anyway, thank you for your help. will keep trying"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457558/how-to-get-rid-of-one-navigation-bar-and-merge-them-as-one-in-android/42460489#comment72073105_42460489) - This chain of comments now looks obsolete.
2. ["Here is  potentialy relevant answer to the question: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authenticating-with-eloquent-and-without-database-how-to-handle-user-roles-and-permissions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104647/laravel-authentication-via-external-api#comment71020066_38104647)
3. ["I fixed it according to this question's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982188/insert-multiple-rows-into-a-mysql-database-from-a-table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298190/retrieving-multiple-data-and-inserting-multiple-data-with-array-and-foreach#comment69800175_41298190) - Should be closed as a duplicate (potentially...my PHP is rusty)
4. ["@CHale you should accept Yow's answer. It'll help others get help faster."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708407/excel-search-array-for-matching-value-from-data-validation-and-then-make-a-calcu/40709280#comment68648230_40709280) - I want to remove it now...
5. ["thank you Xposl works like charm :) you have also one mistake you remove die in your answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397285/session-becomes-empty-when-accessed-in-another-function/40397638#comment68045571_40397638) - Again, should be removed
6. ["Check the link mentioned below
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931571/how-can-change-width-of-dropdown-list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739931/jquery-multiselect-dropdown-list-width-getting-disturb-when-hide-show-dropdown-u#comment66786172_39739931) - Another potential duplicate
7. ["you just put absolutely the same answer I wrote ~half a year ago"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964804/189134) - Post was deleted about a month after my flag

I do have a view built where I can see what the bot has flagged. If you are curious, a screenshot I shared several years ago looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7QUG.jpg)

---

Lastly, I want it known that it does not bother me which way the community decides on this. I have no real opinion on whether it should be run on my own account or under another account.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient priv…oh wait

Comment: That's interesting, out of those 7, are there comments that could have been deleted anyways, or are those really 7 good comments?

Comment: @g00glen00b At the risk of angering my bot...I've updated the answer with the comments.

Comment: That 4th comment should definitely be removed.

Comment: @Andy you said you have no opinion on whether it should run under your account or a separate account.  But as bluefeet mentioned, you are liable for it's performance and violations of the moderator agreement on behalf of your bot. Do you trust your bot enough to not jeopardize your new position if you let it run under your main account

Comment: @psubsee2003 I do. It's only ever been run under my own account because I trust it.

Comment: That I think we should run this under moderator account probably is not surprise, let mods handle more site critical issue, instead of spending hours clicking accept on old *"Thanks great answer comments"*, darn after all we are programmers lets make some use of it!

Comment: With the seven declined flags, was the bot particularly confident about them when flagging? Could you increase the threshold so that at the expense of borderline comments being kept, more comments overall are removed?

Comment: @davidism There is a threshold setting that the confidence must exceed already. Unfortunately, I don't record the confidence levels of a particular post, so I can't see what these were when flagged and I retrain the model periodically. The best I could do would be see how it shakes out today.

Comment: Kudos again for your fantastic work on your bot. As I wrote under Cody's answer, I think we should keep the bot running, but under a different account. The comments flags have rarely been a bottleneck in the overall flag queue, so I don't think we'll suffer by having to review the flags from the bot. Now, if you unleashed it under half a dozen accounts, then we'd have to [beat you with a giant S or something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug).

Comment: What surprises me is that the bot has a declined flag in december 2017. That means we know already how this is going to turn out... :)

Comment: (2) could potentially be useful to future visitors (even more so when the question doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer), (3+6) only makes sense to delete after the post has been closed as a duplicate, (5) why should this be removed? This is pointing out a potential mistake in the answer (I can't tell if the OP is replying to this comment or another comment).

Comment: Seems like a really cool way to dump a lot of busywork on mods. If SE is interested in the results of the bot, why not just onboard it and have it perform comment cleanups on its own?  With the failure rate, and the ability to undelete comment, it would be much less work undeleting the one or two comments someone complains about...

Comment: @Andy I just read [your bot description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically?noredirect=1&lq=1). Could you create a more reserved version of the bot that's run as a mod? Honestly, I'd prefer the original under your account, but understand why people might not. To compromise, would it be possible to have the mod-bot set with higher thresholds for obsolete/chatty comments, then the original bot run under a normie account? Could you even retrain the mod-bot with a lower "good comment" threshold to decrease false positives?

Comment: Perhaps a slightly egregious and leading question, but what is the benefit to flagging/deleting all those comments? I realise there probably isn't an objective measure to use here, but it's an interesting discussion nonetheless. For clarity, I'm quite comfortable with you running the bot under any account, including yours. For me, the success rate you have is amazing and I'm fairly ambivalent about losing the odd potentially useful comment anyway.

Comment: @DavidG the less not useful content on comments, the less readers have to parse to get into the gut without distractions. Remember that comments are transitory by nature and design. SE hasn't gone blade runner on them because people seems to expect them to not be deleted, which every time someone complains it's met with the community nice reminders. :D

Comment: @Braiam I know all this, but is there a *measurable* benefit? OK, so some poor dev has to read a comment or two to get to the useful answer, but if you factor in the time taken to Google, load the page, scroll around the answers etc., surely that time is almost negligible? And like I said, I'm happy for them to go, I was just posing the question, sort-of devil's advocate.

Comment: @DavidG amount of vertical scrolling? Heatmaps? Otherwise, no, I don't know anyone that has done any kind of study, *but* SO claims to be zero chit-chat, and comments were a sort of workaround for the minimum needed chit-chat.

Comment: @Braiam I think there's a difference between trying to keep people on-topic and the chatter to an absolute minimum and *retroactively* cleaning up superfluous comments. Andy clearly has the skills to write an incredibly powerful bot like this, I just wonder if there are more beneficial things he could be targeting?

Comment: @DavidG So [Stack Overflow got about 20 million visits yesterday](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#/trafficCard) (assuming I'm reading this correctly). If even half those users spent one second scrolling past useless comments, that's over 2500 man-hours spent not seeing useful information. Obviously I have no idea if that's a reasonable amount of cumulative time spent scrolling, but with 20 million hits a day, it adds up really quickly.

Comment: @LordFarquaad You may be right, but my point is that you're effectively making up numbers there.

Comment: @DavidG I am absolutely making up numbers. The hits/day seems pretty well logged, but it's tough to tell how much time is spent moving past comments. My counter-point though, is we can probably place a safe lower bound on the amount of time spent, I just took a pretty clearly naive stab at it. If that lower bound's high enough that we decide it's non-negligible, then we can still make decisions without knowing the exact stats. Obviously, though, I'd rather have measurable data to use.

Comment: Andy, can you make your bot open source? When I'm being asked "Do I want to have a black box on some computer have a lot of power?", I'm pressed to saying "No!". If I know what's going on, that's maybe a different thing.

Comment: Is the bot still active?

Comment: No. The bot hasn't been active since I was elected. The consensus has been to now let a moderator bot auto-nuke things and instead keep a human in the process.

Answer (score 107):

I think it's a great idea... Quite honestly, I've been waiting three years for Andy to get elected *in the hope* that he'd want to continue running this thing as a moderator.

Heck, I don't think he should stop at auto-deleting comments in situations where there's a high amount of confidence in some heuristic... I think he should apply those same heuristics to *flags raised by other people*. The recent [changes to comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292011/drop-not-constructive-combine-noisy-reword-rude-and-other-comment-flag) were made with the express intent of making it easier to automate handling of exactly the sort of "noisy" comments already being flagged and deleted by this script. Why? [Because these comments are...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298507/new-no-longer-needed-flag-reason-title-is-incorrect/298511#298511)

> ..."Death by a thousand cuts" - one or two have an imperceptible cost, but in quantity they push the site closer to those tedious forums where finding useful information involves scanning past scores of irrelevant responses. Arguably we could just hide them and be done with it, except that no one can agree on a suitable threshold for doing it - so instead we have flags and rely on moderator judgement.

Human oversight is all well and good, but... How many times does a human have to flag or a moderator have to approve a flag on *"+1 thank you!!!"* before we can decide that these are *always* just noise and can *always* just be deleted after a little while?

A while back, I added heuristics to enable deletion of many of those "thank you" comments with a single flag; that already accounts for around 200 comment deletions on Stack Overflow every day, which is nice... But, why mess around? After three years, we have ample data at both the potential benefit (thousands fewer noisy comments) and the potential harm (once in a blue moon a useful comment gets deleted).

Whether or not Andy wants to take on this challenge is something I'd prefer to leave up to him; I have a few other ideas to try here as well if that doesn't pan out.

### But what about abuse? Oversight? Bears?

Here's the dirty little secret: various mods have been using scripts to speed up tedious repetitive tasks for *years,* whether that's cleaning up off-topic questions in a tag that should never have existed or bifurcating an ambiguous tag, there are lots of tasks where - after a good sanity-check on the script and initial conditions - it's considerably *less* error-prone to let a machine do the heavy lifting than to repeatedly click the same buttons in the same order.

Which isn't to say it's never gone horribly wrong... But the problems I've seen have nothing to do with the inherent advantage of having a human glance at a thousand similar items and try to pick out the one that doesn't belong; they've all fallen into one or both of two other categories:

1. **Lack of preparation**. If you're gonna run something on hundreds of posts or comments, test it on *one* first. Then on two. Then on 10. And so on, checking your work at each step. If you can do a "dry run" that doesn't actually modify anything the first time, do that too - the built-in tools that are potentially destructive tell you what they're gonna do before they do it, yours should as well. It's a lot easier to fix the damage caused by an inverted conditional ahead of time than it is later on after you've mangled half the site.
2. **Lack of accountability.** If you *or* your script delete someone's work and they come asking why, you damn well better tell them - and if it turns out to have been a mistake, you better fix it too. Silence isn't acceptable; neither is blaming it on your crappy scripting abilities.

As far as I'm concerned, those are pretty good pitfalls to watch for even when you're doing everything by hand; avoiding them indicates the kind of skill and care that sets moderators apart from harried forum admins.

*For a better take on potential pitfalls here, see [Pops' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354719/should-moderators-run-automated-bots-under-their-accounts/354734#354734)*

Comment: would SE consider to create dedicated bot accounts for something like this? I would prefer to clearly separate the bot from the real user. It would also add some transparency, as the actions are clearly coming from a bot.

Comment: For something like *this*? I don't see the point; the activity is all but invisible to anyone but moderators. If a mod wanted to, say, go through and close all questions in some huge tag, or leaving automatic comments on new questions or something... I could see setting up a separate account for *that* simply to make it more obvious what was going on.

Comment: So my question - which I was going to leave on the main question until your answer popped up.  If SE is confident enough in Andy's script to allow him to run it, why not give the power to [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)

Comment: That's not out of the question, @psubsee2003 - but it's a "6-8 week after all this other stuff on the backlog" kind of thing. Also... Some things just work better with a small-a agile process; think of how fast projects like SmokeDetector adjust to changes in the nature of spam (external user-run scripts) vs. how many years it takes to adjust the heuristics used for quality-checking new questions (internal logic). In the time it took Andy to delete a hundred thousand comments, I got... a few wording changes to the flag dialog.

Comment: Yes to this. Comments are nice and all but they are just [*temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and as much as I hate when my comments are being constantly deleted, there is no use for them in the long run anyway. Each comment sooner or later should be either converted/edited into an answer and then deleted or just being deleted. In other words, I don't see any real damage that could be potentially caused by automating this process (with moderation privileges).

Comment: Well, hey, if Shog9 is okay with turning it loose, then let's do it.

Comment: I agree that a bot isn't automatically less accountable than a human. I strongly disagree that Andy's bot is currently sufficiently accountable. I understand the thought process by which users and mods decide whether to flag and delete comments. I *don't* know the "thought process" that Andy's bot uses. If it's going to be set loose, there needs to be a mechanism of community oversight. Just making a history of every comment it's flagged publicly visible would be a very good start, assuming that that can be done without any privacy/legal problems. (I can't think of any.)

Comment: Here's a contention. If you at stack like the bot so much, why not just ask andy for the source and run it yourself?

Comment: If just straight up using Andy's bot is a bad idea, perhaps it could somehow be used to display its heuristic by the comments to make it easier for Andy (or even other mods, if he was willing to release his tool to them) to notice bad comments (something like the "our system has flagged this post as possible spam" on reviews). It's not nearly as good, but if the Stack Overflow public isn't comfortable with a bot having moderator privileges, this might be the next best thing.

Comment: The CM team was just talking about this on a call a few hours ago, @Justin. One of the other things I've been investigating is a new service some 3rd-party folks are looking to launch for real-time classification of comments; they just finished analyzing a test block of data I sent 'em, and report 99.5% accuracy - if further tests pan out, this might be something we could wire in as a beefed-up version of what Andy's already been doing, with indicators to let folks know what's going on: UI could be something like, "this comment will be removed in 30...29...28... (dispute)"

Comment: So, self-destructive comments? I dig it.

Answer (score 41):

This question is fascinating because it has turned into a showcase for what is described in *Thinking, Fast and Slow* as [the substitution principle](http://lesswrong.com/lw/9l3/the_substitution_principle/). More specifically, "Should moderators [be able to] run automated bots under their accounts?" seems to have morphed into "how much do I trust full automation?"

There is actually a good deal of prior research in this space. To oversimplify a bit (only because I'm not trying to write a book here):

1. the average human tends to be wary of automation at first
2. if and when automation gets implemented, average people gradually grow complacent and [over-reliant](http://theweek.com/articles/464674/8-drivers-who-blindly-followed-gps-into-disaster) on the machines/systems
3. when the system eventually has a non-trivial failure—and, given enough time, it will, because no system is 100% perfect—average people freak out and overcorrect by getting disproportionately more suspicious of machines than is justified, and generally [showing a pro-human bias](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749597803001158).

Personally, I think that automated systems, **when designed correctly**, and with all other things being equal, are just fine to use.

With that said, let's take a look at this specific case.

- Is the system designed correctly?

  - The evidence presented in the question body and other answers seems
    to indicate that it is. The bot's lifetime accuracy is >99%, and its
    recent accuracy is much better than that.
- How bad are the false positives?

  - As I was writing this post, [the actual comments were posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354723/), and they seem... not-that-false. In the general case, they're only comments, after all. It's uncommon for one to be truly important, and most of the time, when one is, it ought to have been edited into a post body anyways.
- What happens if the bot goes nuts?

  - In theory, this could be as bad as a troll hacking a diamond mod's account, I guess. In practice, the code is probably very comment-specific, so I'd think that the worst that would happen is increased comment deletions until we/Andy shut the bot down.
- What happens if Andy goes nuts?

  - The fact that we're talking about a bot has no bearing on this question. This wouldn't be treated any differently than any other hypothetical case of a moderator "going rogue", bot or not. *If* this were to be allowed, it wouldn't change the "you are responsible for every action taken under your account" rule that is always in place (for all users, including but not limited to mods). Bad actions by the bot would be treated as if they had been made by Andy himself. Users who elected Andy did so because they trusted his judgement, and in his judgement, the benefits of running this bot as a mod justify the potential risks.

Honestly, the security issue (someone compromising the bot and then pivoting to cause havoc on the site) worries me more than the automation one. I don't have a great handle on the scope of that threat, and for that reason I'm reluctant to support the use of this bot, at least for now.

I would be curious to hear what the previous SO mod crew thought of the bot's flags. In addition to having general moderating expertise, they'd be the ones dealing with the trouble and making fixes in case of errors, so they should get an extra voice. Were they glad that the manual review process was there, or did they wish they could be spending their valuable, limited time on dealing with other stuff? (This is actual curiosity; I didn't talk to them before posting this.)

I'm also curious what the marginal benefit of the "mod bot" over the status quo is. After all, the alternative is running the bot under a sockpuppet account, not disabling it entirely. It was already stated that the *types* of comments flagged would not change. How much more activity would the bot produce without the 100-flag/day limit? The bot would still be limited by our API quota, so it's not like it would cause all of SO to come crashing down due to load; this is only a question of oversight work.

Comment: The bot can't go nuts... it is ruled by the 3 laws.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an international company, and as part of our ongoing attempts to be less America-centric, we welcome bots from all around the world. They are not required to follow the Three Laws of Robotics, which are the intellectual property of U.S. Robots and Mechanical Men, Inc., nor do we warrant that they are "Three Laws Safe" (a registered trademark of U.S. Robots and Mechanical Men, Inc.).

Comment: Regarding that security concern...is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129828/186281) an appropriate response?

Comment: More seriously, granular security scopes on the API could help with that concern, but that's obviously not a small change. Should API changes be on anyone's TODO list though, it's something that would be nice.

Comment: `How much more activity would the bot produce without the 100-flag/day limit?` According to the comments under Travis' answer, the bot under moderator-Andy would probably jump to about 300 flags per day instead of 100. So 100k flags every year, instead of every 3 years.

Comment: "... when the system eventually has a non-trivial failure—and, given enough time, it will, because no system is 100% perfect ..." That (non-trivial failure) is the chief reason for my hesitation in voting for the bot to run under a moderator account. Granted, the failure might be easily/quickly rectifiable, but it might not be and you'll only know the extent of the damage when it happens ...

Comment: [Why don't we do both?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354844/7127751) This lets the bot run by itself, but still keeps human supervision on top of it.

Comment: `Honestly, the security issue (someone compromising the bot and then pivoting to cause havoc on the site) worries me more than the automation one.` - How would compromising the bot be different from compromising any other moderator's account? That could happen all the same with or without a bot.

Comment: @Siguza From an outcome perspective, there would be little difference. I based that statement on the assumption that people would notice compromises of their "real" or "personal" accounts more readily than of a bot. But a lot of it was hand waving because I don't know anything about how the actual bot works (I've never even taken a close look at the API internals).

Answer (score 29):

I say we elected Andy *and* his resources.

Flagging is rate limited even for mods (one per 5 seconds), reversible if necessary, and I trust him to be careful with it.

Let's let him put the bot to work in measured stages, and stop forcing people to do manual work that can be easily automated.

Comment: [*"Automation is good, but I think a human touch can go a long ways towards achieving compliance (I have to admit not doing this as much as I'd like)."* –Aaron Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9#post-45152855) Hmm...

Comment: We'll have a lot more time for humans touching humans if we can automate button pushing.

Comment: I am of the mind that one of the major draws of having Andy as a mod is this ^, aka his experience with highly effective, and safe, bot behavior. Though where the line is drawn is a matter of opinion. This answer seems to parrot the accolades in the post, but I'm concerned by bluefeet's comment under my answer; flags are reversible if necessary, but it's apparently next to impossible to determine when it's necessary, at least on a scale like this.

Answer (score 21):

My first reaction is, *109,494 comments were already deleted **with** oversight so the effect of this process is already in play*. I haven't heard any griping about it in the past on meta, and have seen some +1's here for its favor.

However, the limitless approach to this is interesting. I think if the bot can only handle 100 per day, and who knows how many are being produced per day, that it will have a strong chance at success. If the bot matches 50,000 comments and batch removes them, I believe that there is a stronger chance at false positives. I would be curious, *exactly how many comments would it match if it had no limit*? I believe the answer to this question is the fundamental issue presented. If it would delete 50,000 comments all at once, then that would present a concern.

All that said, this is easy to fix from the limitless angle. If the bot could be internally limited to 1,000 comment deletions per day, then that should be more than enough to make progress against undesirable comments while at the same time being slow enough to keep a wary eye on it.

---

Given Andy's additional information that the bot is essentially hardcapped at only reviewing 10,000 comments per day, and of that set perhaps only flagging ( now deleting ) 300 of them, I do not see this is as a concern. That rate is rather slow, and given the historical accuracy of this process I see no reason not to allow it to continue.

Comment: A bit more context: Currently, I can hit 100 comments to flag in less than 10,000 comments. This is as far back as I can go with the API (100 pages times 100 results per page). 10,000 comments is about 5-6 hours worth of comments during the week.

Comment: @Andy - So, given the 10,000 comment API set, you are saying that the bot is hardcapped at some subset of those at any given time? How far prior to 10,000 does it hit 100 comments to flag?

Comment: @TravisJ Correct. I sort of shuffle the starting time each day so it's not always the same window that gets flagged. But, in any 24 hour period, the bot only sees a couple hours worth of flags until it hits it's 100 flag limit and shuts down.

Comment: So without a limit, it would only flag, say, 3 times the current amount daily (300?)-*ish*? I understand that those would be immediately deleted with the current moderator status. But, really, given the history I don't understand what all the fuss is about at this point.

Comment: That sounds about right. I haven't ever done an investigation to see if certain hours produce more that I'd flag.

Comment: What if @Andy only flagged very confident matches under his account, and used a sock to flag ones the bot’s less confident about?

Answer (score 10):

I was initially in full agreement with Cody's answer, but since reading over some of the other information, I've changed my mind. I'd support running the bot under Andy's moderator account **if and only if** some conditions are met:

1. The bot running under Andy's accounts should be **more conservative** in what it deletes. Adjust the confidence thresholds so that say 80% to 90% of what it picks up now would get auto-deleted. This reduces the risk of wrongly deleting comments.
2. Build a **rate limit** into the bot. Make it so it can only delete a certain number of comments in a period. This should help provide safety against a bug causing runaway deletions.
3. Build in a **hard daily limit** on how much it can auto delete. Andy estimates it might flag/delete 300 comments per day. A limit of something like 400 might be good.
4. *Also* **run the bot under a sock puppet that can only flag**, and *this* bot account should be used to test *any* updates and changes before applying them to the bot running under Andy's account.
5. Last and most importantly, develop a **monitoring plan**. This plan could be used both on the sock puppet account and Andy's account. I want a pair of human eyes to at least be checking on the thing periodically. (Maybe once a week at first, maybe once a month later on, maybe eventually never.)

I see the value in using Andy's bot to automate deleting bad comments, but I also want some controls/limits/monitoring to lower the risk of something going horribly wrong. This way, we're giving the system more independence incrementally and testing as we go.

Answer (score 9):

Andy was elected because he was deemed to be the best fit for the role.  His bot *wasn't* elected.

While I've had a mixed feeling towards bots in general, I still feel like they should be eligible to run under their own account.  This way, should there be an actual issue with it, it won't be seen as an overreach of Andy's moderator powers, and it also gives the CM team a single place to look for anomalies should the bot start acting up.

Comment: FWIW I voted for Andy in part because I figured his bot code would be rolled into some moderator or site automation. I'm probably not alone.

Comment: @TylerH:  What a scary thought.  I'd rather have the human making these decisions for me than a bot.  I don't deny that the bot is nifty but it should ***not*** be afforded the same powers as the human.  Or to play even more Devil's Advocate, are you suggesting his candidacy is somehow weaker if he *didn't* have the bot?

Comment: Why is a bot that is more accurate than a human a scary thought? Because it's simply not human? That seems like a frivolous concern. The bot has as few mistakes as a human moderator, and how many moderators have reviewed 100,000+ comment flags?

Comment: And yes, it follows logically that if he did not have the beneficial point of his accurate bot work, then he would be weaker as a candidate (any time you remove a pro from a pros & cons list, the subject will be a weaker choice, obviously). I don't *know* whether I would have voted for him otherwise (he was my #1 candidate), though he certainly *would* still have been in the top 4 candidates to me, even without the bot work.

Comment: @TylerH:  It's about oversight.  **That's the biggest point of emphasis here.** I don't mind the bot - I think it's cool and intend to write my own bot for my own purposes in the future - but if it's being stated that **there will be less visibility into the bot's accuracy**, then that is what scares me.  Attaching it to an account with limitations gives us *public* visibility and allows the CM team to cut that account off without necessarily revoking Andy's privileges.

Comment: Also - I suppose that it's a bit of a shame that he'd be weaker to you if he didn't have the bot.  I hope he's going to be a capable candidate, and I hope that his moderation abilities aren't *exclusively* tied to automation.

Comment: I agree with you that oversight is important. I think oversight is important regardless of its origin - bot or human. And if you look at my answer and comment response under it, you'll see I don't think Andy's bot should be allowed to run under his account because bluefeet said that kind of oversight would be extremely difficult or next-to-impossible.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into that. I don't think he would be unacceptable as a moderator. In fact as I said he would still be in the top tier of candidates to me even without the bot stuff. But there were several great candidates, and even the slightest bullet point on someone's résumé can be enough to give them the edge. For me, the bot work was that edge over people like Cody, Nathan, et al.

Comment: @TylerH `how many moderators have reviewed 100,000+ comment flags` Exactly 1 = Martijn. He has handled 240k+ comment flags.

Comment: @bluefeet And how many of his flags have been reversed, if he doesn't mind that stat being public? If it's more than 7 (or ~40, if you want to go back to earlier iterations of Andy's bot), then there's not much of an argument here; even oversight is just a perfunctory "because it makes us feel good" excuse at that point.

Comment: @TylerH I'd have to dig into the database to get it. Reversing comment flags decisions are weird - the comment would be deleted after a decline or undeleted (which would be very rare). I'm honestly not sure we'd get anything accurate to report on his handled flags.

Comment: @bluefeet Yeah, I figured as much. I'm not surprised that reversing a moderator's comment deletion is not something you would normally keep a tally of... in fact I'd be worried if you needed to! :-)

Answer (score 9):

If the bot is that good at its job and is so well loved, I propose its code get implemented by the SO development team into a permanent feature of the site. That would dissolve this particular discussion of who should run it. It would be similar to the Community user that goes around updating HTTP links to HTTPS ones.

In general, I do not recommend unattended bots for user content. Sure, 99% of the time it was helpful. But those 278 users would probably be pretty upset if their comments were automatically deleted unjustly.

Comment: At the end of the day, those are only comments, and are not that important. I personally don't mind if a bot accidentally deletes one of my comments (And as if I really remember all the comments I posted only yesterday) - Up until now I haven't even noticed that a bot deletes comments on this site

Answer (score 8):

After looking at all of the posts in favor or not in favor, I think it's time for the community managers to author an **automation manifesto**, and **clearly define guidelines** for what is and isn't acceptable for automation within the community.

There's enough chatter here concerning other bots and automation efforts, such as Charcoal, which does raise some concerns.  Tooling like this has also been widely adopted and/or authored by current moderators in some form, if for no other reason than to help lessen their workload.  However, *nothing* about the fact that these bots exist or are being used at all describes *acceptable* usage.

We, the community, can say whether or not we're comfortable with these bots all day if we want to, until we're blue in the face.  As demonstrated by what appears to be a well-split decision, *comfort* is not *acceptable* use.

This isn't really a decision *we* can make anymore.  This needs to be taken up internally with CMs to see what parameters and limits need to be set on power users leveraging tools to handle various tasks.  The fact is, regardless of how comfortable *we* are with bots handling menial tasks for moderators or for detecting anomalies, that won't change the fact that *they're here* and that they hold *some* value.

Answer (score 7):

Run the bot separately, or have it report to Andy *without* flagging comments.

My reasoning isn't too complex.

1. While Andy's bot has been running spectacularly, that's not (to me) a (good enough) reason to give it additional privileges or a larger number of flags per day. Keep it rate-limited to 100 flags a day by putting it on a separate account.
2. Keeping a human eye on the bot is a very good idea, just in case. With the flagging being 99%, it's very accurate. But a human eye is always a good idea. What if something small changes in how people comment, and suddenly it is flagging useful comments? It may take longer to catch this if there isn't a human element.

I have been looking forward to Andy being a mod, partially because of how successful his bot has been, but I don't think bots that delete things without a human eye approving it first are a good idea.

Comment: "The process is running spectacularly" seems to me to be **exactly** a reason to ramp up its effectiveness. The comment flag queue is huge and a low priority for most moderators.

Comment: If Andy wants to make the comment flag queue a priority for him, then I'd suggest he go with my second option: Run it on his account, but turn off the flagging. This way, it will _still_ have his eyes on it before anything is deleted.

Comment: Currently, the comment flag queue is *not* huge, @TylerH. Now granted, that's probably because the bot has been turned off. But since the election, we have stayed *extremely* on top of comment flags. What's really out of control are the "other" flags (though we've beaten those down recently), and that's because they take so much thinking to handle. Comment flags aren't like that. You read the comment, and you click a button.

Answer (score 5):

Tuning in late.

I'd say: if those comment flags are going to increase the moderator workload, **leave them be**. The scarce moderator time available should be used for more pressing manners, such as quickly closing questions that attract low-quality answers where the community fails, handling disputes and educating users (and whatever else it is that moderators do).

Andy [claims](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354719/should-moderators-run-automated-bots-under-their-accounts?cb=1#comment502162_354722) 1 in 100 48-hour old comments is eligible for deletion, while 10,000 comments get posted per 5-6 hours during workdays.

In other words, when unleashed, this algorithm can flag around 15-20 comments per hour. If it would do that, it would generate 360-480 flags per day. Handling those flags costs, at 10 seconds per flag, around one moderator-hour per day.

I'm not debating the accuracy of the algorithm, I'm trying to weigh its usefulness. If nobody else bothered to flag these benign comments, why not let them rot?

On the other hand, if multiple moderators and employees agree with how the algorithm works and believe it is beneficial, then let Stack Overflow incorporate the bot in the site's software and/or run it on some kind of account with moderator privileges (Community?) in order to give it full deletion privileges, so the moderator workload actually decreases (no more 99.9975 Andy flags per day on average to approve) and no single moderator will be to blame for false positives.

Comment: *"and whatever else it is that moderators do"* If you ever figure that out, please let us know.

Comment: @Cody still learning the ropes, eh?

Answer (score 4):

The bot should be allowed to continue to run under Andy's account (assuming my two concerns can be addressed)*^. The bot has some impressive tallies in its favor:

- The threshold is clearly very high - a ~0.25% failure rate over 100,000 flags... that's better than most users.
- Because you say there is automatic logging of moderator actions, the potential for abuse is mitigated, and other mods can see when a comment is deleted by Andy or by someone else.

---

### Concerns:

* One concern I have: If abuse is uncovered, or bad stuff happens, it can be reverted or 'handled' in some way, but how would abuse be uncovered in the first place? At what point would someone realize "OK, Andy - or Andy's bot - has been deleting a ton of comments that shouldn't have been deleted"? What's the safeguard there? Will Andy fork over his bots' specific activity logs? Will the bot's code be integrated into the SO codebase and become the purview of the Community user? Really just asking about considerations, here.

^ A second concern is that Andy's bot will now have access to process *way* more flags/comments than before, given the removal of the 100flags/day limit. Will there be somewhere Andy or the team will comment on the continued success rate of the bot? For instance, after running as a moderator for 30 days, it would be great to have the transparency to see "the error rate rose from 0.25% to 1.5%" (or vice versa).

Comment: There is a possibility (we're looking into it), that the code could be integrated in the codebase. No guarantees, but we're looking. As far as the second concern, since the bots flags would bypass the mod queue, there wouldn't be a success/fail on the flag any longer. The flag would delete the comment singlehandedly, so getting an error would be difficult if not impossible.

Comment: @bluefeet If what you say is true about the 2nd concern, then I would hesitate to allow it to run under Andy's account. Oversight, either real-time or post hoc, is critical for this kind of action.

Comment: There's nothing to say that Andy couldnt provide some kind of a list of recent deleted comments either. I'm sure he already has plenty of logging built-in.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a compromise. **Let's do both.**

Have Andy run the bot under his own account, deleting bad comments (Andy estimates this would delete about 300 comments per day). Also have a sockpuppet account flagging bad comments. This gives us the best of both worlds.

- This lets the bot handle more than 100 comments a day.
- This doesn't fill the review queues any more than the bot currently does.
- However, it still keeps the bot human-supervised. If Andy accidentally flips a conditional in the bot code during refactoring, the sockpuppet account will show a high failure rate or get a review ban, alerting Andy to turn the bot off and roll back deletions done under his account.
- This also allows us to keep a record of the bot's accuracy.

In short, this lets the bot perform greater duties, while still keeping it semi-supervised.

Answer (score -1):

I think a bot deleting (not just flagging) some obvious unwanted comments is a good idea (many way more critical processes are handled just fine by machines with little to no human oversight or intervention), but I can't say whether **this** bot is a good idea.

Yes, the results are good, but AI is AI, there will always be some margin of error. I suppose the question would be: does the benefit to the site outweigh the error? My intuition says "probably", but I can't really be sure - I have to wonder how much harm it does for these comments to stick around and whether mods are more conservative or more liberal in acting on flags.

I personally think there's a lot of room for a bot deleting comments based on manually written patterns - the margin of error there would be inversely proportional to how skilled the person is coming up with the patterns, and that's much easier to improve upon with review and testing.

... although I personally think everyone's time would be much better spent [fixing the functional problems with comments](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/comments-are-not-for-extended-discussion-long-term-solution-discussion) to reduce the need to remove them in the first place.

Comment: Human intelligence is only human, and it will always have a margin of error, too. And bots don't have fat fingers.

Answer (score -4):

I am leaning towards **not** giving the bot moderator privileges, for the simple fact that Stack Overflow is meant to be moderated and maintained by the community.

I think @CodyGray post was spot-on. I also think that relaxing the rate limit for the bot is a good idea. However, I have another suggestion.

---

#### My suggestion

I would be okay if the bot ran under a moderator account, but re-programmed to trigger **only on obvious infractions** of the community guidelines.

This would mean that the bot would take action on comments, such as:

- Spam.
- Harassment, name-calling, etc.
- Plain "thank you" or "+1/-1" comments that [don't provide any additional context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283874/remove-the-limitation-that-stops-comments-from-starting-with-1-or-1/283953#283953).

But **not** on comments that could be considered as:

- Off-topic or non-constructive.
- Obsolete.
- Too chatty.

---

#### My reasoning

By reading this thread (and the other linked posts) it is quite evident that people value the human subjective element over the narrow and objective nature of a bot.

Simple "if-this-do-that" scenarios (e.g spam or "thank you" comments) are easily scripted and suit a bot perfectly in my opinion, because it does not require human intervention. However, many comments are more complex than that and usually require human intuition, reasoning and social intelligence in order to make a qualitative decision. I think this is the main reason people dislike the idea of giving too much power to a bot.

Take a look at our judicial system for example; the law isn't a collection of "if-this-do-that" instructions, but rather a collection of [deontic declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_logic) stating permissible and non-permissible behaviors. We then have judges that interpret the law and combined with the circumstances of each individual case make qualitative decisions. Could you imagine if the judicial system was ran solely by robots? A robot could perhaps interpret the law, but it could not make qualitative decisions because it lacks the human qualities mentioned above.

Of course, we're not dealing with the law here, but there are some resemblances nonetheless. The community guidelines here on Stack Overflow need, just like the law, interpretation and somebody that administers that interpretation.

The point I am trying to make is that for simple "if-this-do-that" cases I don't see a problem with a bot intervening. However the more complex cases require human intervention regardless of the bots statistical accuracy of past flaggings.

---

#### TL;DR

- Allow a toned-down version of the bot to run with moderator privileges, deleting only comments whose violation do not require human intervention because they always result in the same action taken (e.g blatant spam, harassment, etc).
- Flagged comments whose nature may or may not be deemed as violation depending on subjective opinion and the circumstances will be left for human review.

Comment: \*cough* [roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-delete) mean anything to you?

Comment: I don't know the full extent of functionality of the bot, but I don't think the auto-delete functionality of the site is as efficient as the bot. Hence my point.

Comment: Roomba works on completely objective criteria. I haven't scrutinized the source code for Andy's bot, but I'm pretty sure it does not. Not a good analogy here.

Comment: @CodyGray fair enough. In that case I suppose I would vote 100% no for the bot.

Comment: @Chris Just to clarify, what Cody was referring to as "completely objective criteria" is that deletion of content by the roomba is based on standard metrics: age, score, activity, etc. These are all things that can be measured, but none of them have anything to do with the content itself. When dealing with the written content and evaluating it using heuristics, natural language processing, regex, etc., things become much less objective, and much more relative. A bot that was limited only to completely objective criteria would probably be much less effective and accurate.

Answer (score -5):

No, for the simple fact that while this bot may be accurate and running effectively we know that isn't always the case. There are cases where someone may have a bot that shouldn't be running with moderator privileges due to issues they have had/currently may have.

This brings up the question if this bot is approved to run as a moderator does that mean all bots have blanket approval to run on moderator accounts? Or does each bot need to be approved individually? What happens when the bot gets updated/improved, will it need to be re-approved for use?

I would suggest that in the long run if a bot is considered appropriate to run on a moderator account that it might be better to bring it into the official code base. In my opinion if this bot was allowed to run without flagging limitations it would be a smaller load on the servers if it was running within the system rather then as an api call.

Comment: I don't think anyone here would argue that an approval of this proposition interprets it to be a blanket approval for all bots.

Comment: @TylerH To be fair the question title is "Should moderators run automated bots under their accounts?" and not about a specific bot.

Comment: That is a fair point, but I think it's overruled by the fact that this is the first (to my knowledge) instance of this, and the *entire* OP talks exclusively about Andy's bot and the implications of letting it run under a moderator account. Any other might probably will have a different rate of success, and perform a different function (however similar, and regardless of whether it's better or worse at its job), and so therefore will need to be inspected on its own merits. Letting all bots in here would be like letting all users with 100k rep be mods after the first 100k rep user gets elected.

Comment: @TylerH It should also be noted that there is a post in here stating that scripts are already being run on moderator accounts in order to reduce the amount of work being done. With that it is easy to take this question as applying to all moderators and not just this case.

Comment: To be fair, the user scripts you're referencing are on a different scale from Andy's bot. Yes, they are both cases where task automation is at play, but user scripts typically require an action to be initiated by the human, and run at a much smaller scale. They can choose to not run the script each time they go to do the action. Andy's bot runs pretty much without any input from him to get started, and has been going nonstop for 3 years.

Comment: Perhaps every moderator should be assigned a bot..

Answer (score -10):

TL;DR: Create a new type of account, a bot account.

---

**Considerations:**

- Assuming the community decides to allow this bot to have its own separate account without limits, it will very quickly accumulate a very high Stack Overflow score.
- That will probably give it many more abilities and remove many limits that some of us might not agree that a bot should have.
- Maybe there are other privileges that a bot should have (even a new one), like removing or changing limits of activities.

So I think what we should do is create a new type of account. A bot account, and then the community can discuss what privileges a bot should have.

**Who knows, maybe by the next moderator elected will be a bot.**

Comment: I don't think we should be encouraging people to create bots to screw around on [so]. One person did it and it worked pretty well, but if every other person starts doing it, that's just going to create a whole lot **more** work for the mods (by needing to either deal with way too many false flags or deal with the messes the bots made). Also, this bot only flags - flagging doesn't grant reputation and it's not some sentient AI that can figure out how to use any privileges it's given (at least not yet).

Comment: @Dukeling I hate to tell you this, but lots of people are already doing this. And far from "screwing around", they provide some VERY useful aids for moderation (I'm talking mere mortals as well as mods). As long as the bots are cordoned off and aim to do one thing(and do it well), it isn't an issue.

Comment: @Dukeling That is exactly my point, since people are already doing it, we may as well do it the right way. create a bot account, it will only be able to flag, but unlimited flags, etc...

Comment: Replace all moderators with bots.