# Instantly deleted comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, users

There's a high point count user who posts a lot of answers in a tag I read. The answers are generally okay, but occasionally when someone asks a tricky question, I find the answers are wrong. I leave a comment about why I think it's wrong, and I sometimes downvote it.  I may also post a correct answer, but not always.  (I suspect the user is upvoting their own questions to get points, or maybe they just have a lot of fans who instantly upvote anything they write.)

Each time I downvote one of their answers and sometimes when I don't, I get a comment addressed to me complaining about the downvote.  The latest one threatened to "flag" me; not sure what for.

The weird thing is that these comments instantly disappear.  If I draft a response, it isn't accepted, because the comment I'm replying to is gone.

What's going on here?  If I write a comment and then delete it, will the recipient still see it before it disappears?  Or does this user have enough points to know when I read, and maybe to automatically delete the comment?  Or is this all just a coincidence, someone deletes these comments between the time I read them and the time I submit my reply?

Comment: They're just cleaning up their own useless comments. Feel free to flag such comments that complain about curation as no longer needed. Don't feel compelled to respond to them.

Comment: _"If I draft a response, it isn't accepted, because the comment I'm replying to is gone"_ What do you mean by "isn't accepted"? Comments aren't dependant on other comments. You can reply to an imaginary person and the comment should be posted just fine.

Comment: The user is deleting their own comments. Ordinary users (IE non-community moderators) cannot tell that you have viewed their comments through the SO system. A nefarious user might embed an in-line image into their answer and review the logs of download, but this seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @41686d6564:  I got a big red warning message and my comment wasn't accepted.  The message contained some text I didn't write down.  If it happens again, I'll record it.

Comment: "I think the point count is important: maybe there are privileges for high count users that I don't know about." - there aren't. The last privilege is at 25000 rep. There's some swag and free attention afterwards, but there's literally no difference between 25000 and 1 million in terms of privileges

Comment: @Zoe, that should be part of an answer, you shouldn't delete that part of my question.

Comment: Without an example, nobody can know why the comment(s) were deleted. Even with example(s), only moderators can see that information. I'd note, however, that comments are only deleted by: A) the user deleting their own comment; B) enough flags raised on the comment (1 or 3 flags, depending on the comment's contents); or C) a moderator deleting the comment, primarily in response to someone raising a flag on that comment, although moderators do delete comments when they see them in the moderator's own use of the site and in response to some flags on the question and/or other answers or comments.

Comment: @Makyen:  I can give you the name of the user and two posts where this happened, but I'd rather not do it in public:  maybe this really is just a coincidence.  Is there a way to send this to you privately?

Comment: @user2554330 If you think there's a real issue, that's what "in need of moderator intervention" flags are for.

Comment: @Makyen:  I will flag one of the cases.  If you want me to flag more, let me know.

Comment: Let them know about the instant upvotes too.

Comment: "I suspect the user is upvoting their own questions to get points..." You can't upvote your own questions and answers.

Comment: @jamesdlin they likely meant sockpuppeting. Still, good point - indeed one can't do that.

Comment: The problem you describe with regard to not being able to post a comment would be possible if the answer or question is deleted. Not if another comment is deleted.

Comment: Do your comments contain `-1`? If so it is by design you will see a "big red warning message" https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiTrx.png

Comment: @MartinSmith:  I don't think that's the message I saw.  I'm guessing what happened is that the message was in my Inbox when I checked, but when I clicked on it to go the article to respond, that failed.  That's not exactly how I remember it, but my memory may have confused two separate incidents.

Comment: *"I suspect the user is upvoting their own questions to get points, or maybe they just have a lot of fans who instantly upvote anything they write."* The latter is **entirely** likely if they have a high reputation. I've posted *completely, mind-numbingly* wrong answers to questions and had them reach a score of 3 or 4 before either I realized how I'd got it completely wrong or someone else did and was kind enough to comment to tell me. Human nature I guess, to trust an "authority" (even though high rep != authority).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This kinda smells like a user who is intentionally posting a nasty comment and then deleting it a few moments later, hoping its target has seen it, but avoiding repercussions from moderators…

Of course, I could be completely overthinking this.

If this happens a lot, you *could* apply a custom flag to the post where this happened and explain the situation. Moderators can see deleted comments. If any user makes a habit out of this, in my opinion, it's just not nice.

Comment: IMO it's not that it's just not nice, they're actively avoiding repercussions for potentially breaching the code of conduct. If that's the case, it's far more "sinister" and should probably be handled as breaching the code of conduct.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Yes, IF that's the case. But it can be hard to see if that's the reason, or if they simply realized after posting that the comment was a bit too much. The latter has happened to me a few times when I'm in a hot argument.

Comment: The more charitable reading is that said individual is posting a nasty comment and then immediately thinking better of it...

Comment: In the _don't assume malice_, these might very well be comments that could be flagged by a bot or someone actively screening new comments ([Andy was running one in 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354719/7296893)) and instantly deleted because of a keyword and a flag. I don't know if there is a bot/person actively monitoring new comments atm, though.

Comment: @ErikA: If such a bot were running, the comment author could intentionally be posting malicious comments, which get nuked quickly... In that case: Yay, malice, but dealt with swiftly! :D