# Comment filter detection of "specific guidance" is broken

Tags: bug, comments, downvotes

This screenshot says it all.

[image]

I did provide specific guidance, which the comment filter failed to recognize.  In particular, I specifically identified the mistake in the answer and suggested what it should say instead.

Until the filter is capable of actually differentiating between informative comments and noise, it needs to go away.

Comment: Related: [Remove the limitation that stops comments from starting with +1 or -1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283874/359284)

Comment: @Kevin: Related yes, but this is about failure of the revised rules.  The ones that supposedly "fixed" the problem and marked the other as status-completed.

Comment: I don't see any *specific guidance*. Specific guidance would be *Your premise is faulty, because a boolean does not default to true (it is actually undefined behavior). You should correct your post.*. Instead, you *commented on your downvote*, which is precisely what the error message indicates.  While I agree that the filter needs quite a bit of work, this one seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @Ken: So in your opinion it hinges on appending "You should correct your post"?

Comment: No, it hinges on *providing specific guidance*, and I don't see *-1, because you're wrong.* as being anything specific.

Comment: @KenWhite: My comment is every bit as specific as your suggested "improvement".  The difference is that your version has more noise.  Oh, also that your version is flat wrong.  The answer saying that boolean DOES default to true is wrong.  Your version saying that boolean DOES NOT default to true is wrong.  The behavior is undefined, you can make no other statement about it.  But meta is not the place for discussing C++ specifications.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug since this is by design:

> It appears that dropping this restriction for comments that exceed 120 characters in length would preserve the bulk of the positive benefits, while getting out of the way of folks who're taking the time to write reasonably informative content.
>
> So that's what I've done. I've also re-worked the guidance presented upon encountering the block:
>
> ~ [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) , [source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953/3041194)

While it's kind of not cool to ban user's, especially high rep users like yourself, from saying what they want in comments *because it might possibly cause the OP to go rogue and downvote some of your posts out of spite, which then might cause you to email SE, which then would cause more work for some people at SE over a few non-statistically significant fake internet points,* I'd suggest just trying to work around it.

So you could just reword that to

> Claiming a boolean defaults to true is incorrect. It really is undefined behavior.

Also, while your correct in that you did provide specific guidance. You didn't adhere to the line before it:

> Don't comment on your downvote.

So seems it's working like intended in that regard.

Comment: Yes, and that implementation of the specific guidance detector is rather buggy.