# Why can't we put += 1 in a comment?

Tags: discussion

I was writing a comment on an answer, and when I tried to add `+= 1` to the comment, when I went to add my comment it said it's not allowed. Why is that?

`+= 1` is used all the time in programming, so it's silly that we can't put that in a comment.

[image]

Comment: @Jeroen it's `+= 1` at least on regular stack and not the meta

Comment: @GNKeshava I tried it again and it worked, it's strange it didn't work before

Comment: @GNKeshava I added a screenshot proving I'm not crazy

Comment: Jeroen answered this already, but I'll add... Try to write comments that add something useful to the post or conversation. Commenting on [a self-confessed off-topic comment from years past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290316/difference-between-vectorbegin-and-stdbegin#comment41252712_26290316) isn't likely to help folks confused by `std:begin()`; it's just noise.

Comment: @Shog9 I put my comment there because I didn't want to bother a stranger with a notification, that's my own post :P when I was writing a comment, I was putting it on another post, where someone was incrementing an array and I was going to suggest ++ isntead of += 1

Comment: Ah, you're right; I missed [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731699/have-to-get-the-number-of-letters-in-an-arraylist-of-strings/32731767#32731767). Just add an explanation of why ++ might be preferable then.

Comment: They are afraid of... injection. :D

Comment: i += 1'd this..

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283874/1157054 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314/1157054

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Ahh yes, seems to be a bug with the "don't write +1 comments" rule. If you don't use it at the start of the comment you can circumvent the restriction, see here:

[image: plus one comments]

Note that the first one does work. Just rephrase so the `+1` bit isn't at the start of your comment.

Nitpicking, a comment like:

> `+1` is all you need to fix `myFunc`, after that it runs just fine...

should probably get through the filter that triggers the warning.

A quick fix may also be be to have the red box include some tip on *why* it thought you were "commenting on your upvote", e.g.:

> Your comment seems to contain "+1" of some sort. Please don't comment on your upvote.

In any case, no biggy. Plenty of workarounds, quick fixes, and pragmatic solutions available (including: just leaving the inconvencience).

Comment: The check doesn't even particularly care if there's a +1 in the comment, as long as it's not a very short comment that *starts* with it. Gobs and gobs of noisy "+1 thanks" comments blocked by that.

Comment: Number of times this feature stopped me from posting a noisy comment: 0.  Number of times I noticed that Shog9 treats me like an idiot: 3.

Comment: @HansPassant Woa, what's with the hostility? That was uncalled for IMO. In any case, it seems to me a genuine attempt to prevent noisy comments, and even if it doesn't prevent *you* or other power users from posting noise, it may well help prevent noisy comments from less experienced users.

Comment: Sure, treating me like an idiot is a pretty good way to get me hostile.  We have a number for that, pretty sure it says I'm a *reputable* user and not an idiot.  Use it.

Comment: @Shog, Why not leave the old rules as they were and just allow these chars when we use backticks to signify code? So += is not allowed, '`+=`' is allowed.

Comment: Thats why we shouldnt have regex checks or anything that tries to filter "+1 good answer" out, because there will always be a way around it...and so we've solved nothing yet but made it all the more difficult to comment.  While at the same time we break other things such as this example...+=1

Comment: Were some comments deleted? I am completely lost by this conversation about whether or not Shog9 is treating @HansPassant "like an idiot."

Comment: @KyleStrand - No, no one is calling any one an idiot, its just Hans being Hans...he doesn't like this "feature"...and Shog has good intentions but I too agree this was a bad feature...It almost never works right.

Comment: @JonH How do you know it never works right? Just because you never try to post the type of comment it's supposed to block and therefore only see false positives doesn't mean there aren't enough true positives that it blocks to warrant the occasional inconvenience.

Comment: @Michelle - To me who cares if someone wants to post "+1 thanks works great" it's a comment...a comment...nothing more than a comment.  It shouldn't be filtered out, besides it causes more harm than what its worth, in fact here is a perfect example.

Comment: @JonH Honestly, if the comment thread here would be anything like the rest of the internet I think SO would lose a lot of users. The entire point of SO is to make it a hard cold efficient place and rules like this contribute a lot to that.

Comment: I hate this "feature" too. Trying to filter every user input like "+1", "thanks" is just a waste of resources. I'm just getting angry when I can't post a comment because of stupid rules like this one.

Comment: ‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭+1

Comment: lol this isn't a "bug"; it's Shog casting the net as wide as possible when he banned everyone's sensible comments then got surprised when people started gently modifying them to work around :P Yes, folks, that's right: he literally banned leading `+= 1` because he hates +1 comments so much.

Comment: @duplode sorry for how my comment came across. It wasn't meant to be snarky, it was meant to be taken literally - "don't get too high an opinion of yourself based on your reputation score, we all have a little idiot in us somewhere". Maybe it came across as "with your high rep you're still an idiot", but what I meant was "with high rep you're still _capable of being_ an idiot, just like the rest of us". I was also trying to point out that Hans was taking something personally that wasn't directed at him, and _by his own admission_ got hostile. I'm disappointed that my comment was removed.

Comment: @Shog9 So do you also hate "+1 because *<comment on particularly good part of post>*"?

Comment: (The users of this site are programmers. Trying to block them from something with a programming algorithm will likely just encourage them further to find a smart way around it.)

Comment: There's a length-check that applies, @immibis.

Comment: @Shog9 Many times I've been blocked from posting "+1 because *<comment on particularly good part of post>*". How long is the length threshold?

Comment: @immibis See above where Shog also mentions in a comment about "*starts* with +1" (emphasis both his and mine, actually). I suspect that "starts with" supersedes the length check.

Answer (score -15):

This feature has been designed to avoid "thanks" spamming (as Shog9 said). However this is not so good an idea.

If I want to spam using that kind of messages I will do that regardless of just few filters...

In my opinion, instead of this waste of resources we should believe in **power of the community**, which will find and vote to remove such comments.

Comment: -1: Actually, it was to prevent the leading vote indicator in comments like this, that may otherwise not be "spam" or "thanks" whatsoever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So "+1" comments are banned but "-1" comments are OK?  Strange...

Comment: @MasonWheeler That is to encourage users to leave a comment when downvoting, a much requested *feature*...

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Nope; the filter is automatically turned off for longer comments, so that you can say "+1" instead of "I have decided to upvote you good kind sir well done good job" and avoid truncating the actually meaningful part of your comment. Completely ridiculous.