# Unable to comment: "Comments cannot contain that content."

Tags: bug, comments

I'm curious why the error was triggered for my comment:

[image]

It says *"Don't comment on your upvote."*, but I did not update that answer either.

I was able to comment by adding a *"FWIW"* at the beginning of the comment.

---

I can confirm that it's likely related to the [`+1` blocking logic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314) mentioned here, because this would work without issue:

```
`! + [2,2,3]` is `true`. `!` is an operator, not a value.
```

But that's not the code the OP posted in their question...

So I know *why* now, but maybe there is a rule that can/should be tweaked to allow my case.

I also understand that the parsing rules should probably not be public knowledge.

**However**, since it was not my intention to post `+1`, the error message didn't make any sense to me. It should be improved to make it clear what happened if you *accidentally* run into this.

---

Similar issue (duplicate): [Why can't we put += 1 in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306656/218196)

Again, I think the error message could be improved to follow the [principles of least astonishment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306656/218196).

Comment: It was probably triggered by the `1 +`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: There is no `1 +`, but I see know that `! + [1,2,3]` would contain `+1` after stripping some punctuation marks. Still quite unexpected. Maybe an unfortunate side effect of keeping comments clean, but the pre-processor seems a bit too eager here (so maybe still a bug).

Comment: @FelixKling I think "keeping comments clean" is an overstatement, in my experience, anyone that receives this error message will just get around it by putting something else at the beginning of the comment. It's funny, Stack dev's basically refuse to implement anything like this with different rules, but they keep stuff like this around

Comment: @FelixKling: there is a `1 +` typo there, hold the shift key for the `1` and you get `! +`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So `1 +` is also disallowed as a variation of `+ 1`? But then why would I be able to post  `! + [2,2,3]` ?

Comment: Hrm, not sure if that's actually the case, or that it just ignores the `[` in between.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, I just tested, I can actually post a comment with just `1 + ...............`. I mean I get that the rules should not be obvious. But the error message should at least be understandable for people who *accidentally* run into this.

Comment: @Robert: If any it's a duplicate of [Why can't we put += 1 in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306656/218196). I still think that the error message could be improved considerably. The current implementation violates the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: I suppose in some ways this is a duplicate, if you accept that the current consensus here is still "Plenty of workarounds, quick fixes, and pragmatic solutions available (including: just leaving the inconvencience)."... I personally don't think so, but hey, we talked about it 3 and a half years ago so there's that...

Comment: @TravisJ: Sure, I get that. I'd still like to see a better error message. I had a no idea what this message means and why I get it (and I visit the site often ;) )

Comment: that comment doesn't seem to be requesting clarification or suggesting changes.