# How to comment citing the OP which contains `-1`

Tags: support, comments, quality-filter

In some DOS question, the file mask was given as `*-1`. How would you quote that in a comment if you e.g. want to ask for clarification?

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried:

- ``` *-``1 ``` in order to separate the minus from the 1.
- `*-`&#8203;`1` using a zero width space, but other than in a question´, it does not get rendered

I have seen the question *[Why can't we put += 1 in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306656/why-cant-we-put-1-in-a-comment)*. I am not asking why such a rule is in place. I'd rather like to know about the

> Plenty of workarounds, quick fixes, and pragmatic solutions available

because my approaches didn't work.

Comment: If you make the comment more "substantial", it won't get blocked by the "-1 because x" filter. or maybe just rephrase it so the -1 isn't at the start? i dunno

Comment: Prefix it with something like “The string”. The regex responsible for this is rather naive, because it only has a simple job to do.

Comment: @KevinB: How do I make it more substantial? That's all there is to say

Comment: for example, "Your file mask <..> will not match <...> because <...>, is that intentional?"

Comment: Your file mask `*-1` will not match `knomBk-2.4` because `knomBk-2.4` does not contain a `1`. You have a `2` inside and a `4`, but not a `0` and not a `1`. You have a `-`, which matches the filter. You don't have a `+`, but you actually don't need one. Is that intentional? Is my comment substantial enough for you? I could elaborate more, if you like. I think I could write a book about it.

Comment: Yeah, indeed works... :-)

Comment: There is another workaround: writing an answer. You wouldn’t necessarily know it from reading some of my answers, but these are *generally* a bit shorter than a book. They also aren’t subjected to naive regexes. If you have enough to say that you could turn it into an answer, you probably should. Even when requesting clarification on a possible mistake in a question, there’s a thin line between comment and answer. Prefer the answer.

Comment: @CodyGray: ok, got it. In [this particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718690/want-to-zip-all-the-contentsfiles-folders-inside-4-different-folders-which-are/58719369#58719369) it would not have been a good answer.

Comment: @ThomasWeller *How do I make it more substantial?* Append a wee poem or limerick to your comment ... "A coder who left Rajistan, discovered an `enum` bad plan..."

Comment: I like how this is closed as a duplicate, although I have already mentioned how the duplicate does not answer my question. Wow.

Comment: The answer starts with a workaround. *"If you don't use +1 it at the start of the comment, you can circumvent the restriction*" followed by a screenshot which demonstrates that

Answer (score -3):

HTML entities don't work in comments ([feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193468/270345)). You can use an actual ZWNJ instead (for example, in bash, with `printf '\u200c'`). Oddly enough, it wasn't inserting a ZWNJ between `-` and `1` that worked for me, but inserting it before `-` (either after `*` or before `*`):

```
`*‌-1` will not match `knomBk-2.4`.
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯