# "Comments cannot contain that content", but similar comment appears to be allowed

Tags: feature-request, comments

I'm trying to comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984561/months-to-pay-off-a-credit-card-function-returns-nan-or-0-0) to say:

> `(-1/30)` is integer division, and is equal to zero. This probably isn't what you mean.

And I'm being told

> Comments cannot contain that content
>
> Do not comment on your downvote. If you think this question can be *improved*, please offer **specific guidance**. See: **The Comment Privilege**.

I've not downvoted, and I am surprised that such a comment is being blocked, as it (removing the "This probably isn't what you mean" doesn't work either).

The comment (posted by another user):

> You should be aware that `APR /= 36500`; and `(-1/30)` are integer divisions.

seems to be allowed.

I don't understand what the difference between these comments is in terms of what is being disallowed.

---

It appears that this is being triggered by the fact that the first significant content of the comment is "-1", which is erroneously considered a downvote comment - especially surprising when you've not downvoted.

Changed to feature request: the message should be improved to give a hint as to the reason. For example:

> Comments cannot start with "-1".
>
> Do not comment on your downvote. If you think this question can be *improved*, please offer **specific guidance**. See: **The Comment Privilege**.

But additionally, including the signal of whether the user has downvoted could be taken into account.

Comment: looks like the system thought the comments were along the lines.. _-1 because..._

Comment: Oh, you mean it's being triggered by the `-1` in `-1/30`? Well, that's awesome...

Comment: @SurajRao yeah, that seems to be it, it works just fine for `-2/30` and other values.

Comment: You could just prefix it with "be aware that..." but yes - it's because of the reason mentioned by @SurajRao. It's not a bug - just means you have to rewrite your comment a little bit.

Comment: @JonClements sure, if you realize that's the problem - the message could be prefixed with "Your message starts with -1." :)

Comment: @JonClements.. Its more like a false positive..

Comment: @SurajRao which is going to happen given the simplicity of the check

Comment: @Andy it does say *Do not comment on your downvote* which should give a decent hint as to why. Maybe instead of a bug report you want to make this a feature request with some reasoning and suggested wording?

Comment: @JonClements well, that's a decent hint, provided you're in the habit of writing downvote comments, you're not quoting content from the question, *and you've actually downvoted*.

Comment: Not really a bug, although, this is certainly an edge case. Perhaps it would have been beneficial for there to have been a link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314/1026459

Comment: True... Except the check is never going to be that exhaustive - it'd be overkill. Perhaps the wording could be better or some reference to something included but for the number of cases this'll happen.... who knows...

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs it's not applied to meta :)

Comment: @AndyTurner: Testing if you've actually downvoted doesn't work, some people leave the explanatory comment before casting the vote.

Comment: @Ben yes, I'd considered that. Well, test if they've left a DV comment before letting them DV. I know, you've got to stop somewhere; saying clearly why the comment action is being blocked is more useful.

Comment: But, saying clearly why something is blocked goes against the general philosophy that SE uses of making it harder for people to get around such blocks by keeping the details of the actual checks secret.

Comment: _But additionally, including the signal of whether the user has downvoted could be taken into account._ - well, not really. Because such a thing would allow a user to take away their downvote, comment, then downvote again to "game" the system (or simply comment before downvoting...). The system cannot tell the intent of a user.

Comment: @Makyen: People will get around it anyway.  Everyone commenting on this answer knew the problem almost immediately on seeing the question.  I feel like we're in an [xkcd strip](https://xkcd.com/1028/).

Comment: +1 good question.I think the reason yours isn't allowed is because the comment _starts with_ `-1`, whereas the other comment just has it within the comment.

Comment: Meanwhile, idownvotedbecau.se links are allowed. This makes no sense.

Comment: I have only seen idownvotedbecau.se recently - they might be a new thing that hasn't been blacklisted yet. Maybe it's worth a meta post to see if that should be blocked too?

Comment: @the4kman well.. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended

Answer (score 68):

The `-` Dash (as part of a "`-1`") just can't be at the beginning of the comment.  It needs to be preceded by text (other than brackets/symbols):

[image: screenshot example]

Alternatively, if someone *really* wanted a dash or a "minus one" at the beginning of the comment, you *could* use an *[En Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash)* `–1`.  Similarly, `+1` is not allowed, but `＋1` *is* allowed.  The automatic [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) trimming   can   be   bypassed   with   symbols   too.
                                                                <sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>I wonder if anyone will even notice this **Teeny Tiny** Right-Aligned text...  *Super-cool or Super-silly?*</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup>

If someone *really* wants the world to know who down-voted, they should just use the matching Unicode [sym](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25BC)[bols](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25B2) (▼ & ▲)...

Comment: Not exactly.. if you look at the discussion.. -2 worked

Comment: –1 because I dislike your comment.

Comment: ▼ Down-voted because I'm having a bad day, so I'll punish everyone
 else.

Comment: -V Down voted because the user isn't trying to downvote, he's trying to insert a piece of inline code, and em dashes don't work in code, so that would cause confusing when the code is being pronounced by a screen reader

Comment: I realize that, I was being facetious!

Comment: −1, if I want to say minus, I use minus (U+2212), not the En Dash

Comment: −1  ← There's a symbol that isn't a hyphen or dash, it's a minus, so it works in code *and* at the beginning of a comment.

Comment: Exactly as I said, [U+2212](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2212)…

Comment: ＋1 for beating me to it!

Comment: Something I never noticed until just now is that the spacing between comments doubles-up on certain ones like @Holder's last 2 comments, and only 1 of mine.  Or maybe it's just rendering strangely in my browser?  (My vision is getting bad, so I *had* to [double check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRg8M.png), lol)

Comment: Also [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a bunch of other workarounds

Comment: Summary: implementing a dumb script to trick smart coders who work with scripts all day wasn't the best idea SO ever had...

Comment: +1 for the animation. Regarding your question, I think it is a bit of both, silly (or rather pointless) and cool at the same time.

Comment: ±1 Schrödinger's comment

Comment: – for Schrödinger's poor kitty cat

Comment: … −([ℏ2]÷[2m])÷([d2ψ(x)]÷[dx2+V(x)ψ(x)]) …ғᴏʀ ᴍᴀᴋɪɴɢ ᴍᴇ sᴘᴇɴᴅ ½ʜʀ ʀᴇsᴇᴀʀᴄʜɪɴɢ Sᴄʜʀöᴅɪɴɢᴇʀ.

Comment: I wonder if anyone will even notice this Teeny Tiny Right-Aligned text... Super-cool or Super-silly?

Comment: ^ 

Super-cool or Super-silly?

Why not both???

Comment: @Lundin A) As evident from the question itself, a vast majority of users don't know what script does, B) without the knowledge that the script rejects comments starting with + or -, one wouldn't be able to figure out a workaround, C) even if someone can work around the script, it serves as an indication of a bad practice, thus encouraging the user to convey their thoughts differently. And, D) the plus or minus character required to make the comment work are not on the person's keyboard - which makes it a bit more difficult to exploit the workaround. I'd say the script is pretty effective!

Comment: @Lundin no wonder the proposal which implemented that was the most downvoted post on MSO for 3 years.

Comment: @Lundin Actually it is pretty effective and a pretty good idea; the vast majority of positives caught by this *are* dumb +1/-1 comments that don't contribute anything substantive. The auto-delete aspect of flagging such comments is incredibly worthwhile as well. The few false positives this catches are well worth it, especially considering the real goal of making people only write substantive comments is easily achieved here. If a +1/-1 comment is actually worthwhile, the commenter will be forced to think about what they are saying and find another, better way to say it.

Comment: @TylerH At this point, it doesn't really matter what it does and doesn't, because there's an overwhelming community consensus stating that this is a bad and unwanted feature. Apparently freedom of speech was regarded as more important to the community than reducing spammy comments. From there on, SO can be a democracy or it can be something else.

Comment: @Lundin Well SO is a private company, not a democracy. Comparisons to types of government always fall flat for numerous reasons. At any rate, this isn't about freedom of speech, it's about a company implementing a system to remove content from its platform that it doesn't want.

Comment: @TylerH - I gotta jump in on this: SO *does* hold [democratic moderator elections](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/02/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) and I believe the evolving community self-moderation model is key in [what's driving SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/31/stack-exchange-2017-review/) towards becoming the standard go-to programming wiki.  Sure, the company's making big bucks ([while constantly adapting](https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/02/stack-overflow-lays-off-staff/)), but so are *we* (or we wouldn't be here right now.)

Comment: @Lundin - on the other hand, I don't think this is a bad/unwanted feature.  You have to have a certain knowledge level to be able to "thwart" the system, and I can see how an excess of `+1` or `me too` comments cluttering.  But if the community's mixed, perhaps a filter option would be nice, ie., "☑ ʜɪᴅᴇ ᴀʟʟ +1 ᴄᴏᴍᴍᴇɴᴛs"... Maybe right next to "ʜɪᴅᴇ ᴜɴɪᴄᴏᴅᴇ ғʀᴏᴍ: ☑Eᴠᴇʀʏᴏɴᴇ  ☑Jᴜsᴛ ᴀsʜʟᴇᴇᴅᴀᴡɢ".

Comment: @ashleedawg SO holds democratic moderator elections to moderator behavior. The system that blocks and auto deletes +1 / -1 comments was implemented above that level, by the company. You can see Shog and Jon's explanations of why this was beneficial https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953/2756409 And, frankly, the fact that people are complaining about not being able to type +1 or -1 to indicate votes **when there's a vote option right there on the left** is a little absurd. Save your sympathy for the edge cases like OP here, but don't use the tired and already-debunked 'voting' argument.

Comment: @ashleedawg In other words, such a filter forces people to write better quality content when they comment. That alone is reason enough, let alone the other reason of lightening the heavy load on moderators and reducing comment arguments and revenge voting.

Comment: @TylerH SO frequently claim to be community-driven in advertisement. Sure it is a private company and not a democracy. So that makes it a... "hypocracy"?

Comment: @TylerH - I'm not saying the +/-1 think isn't silly. It's so silly, in fact, that as soon as I realized it was "a thing", my next step was to try to defeat it (bypass #1 worked).  i also think it's silly that I get punished for helpful newbies since they can't upvote my answers, plus their questions are *even more* of a pain because of the no-pics thing.  ..,.but unfortunately, everything on the planet that is used by more than 3 people needs to cater to the lowest common denominator. In this case. But tell me, **how many ppl are actually complaining about this?** What percentage? <0.0001%?

Comment: @ashleedawg You get the privilege to upvote long before you get the privilege to comment. So arguing that people should be able to comment +1 because they can't upvote doesn't hold water.

Comment: @Lundin community-driven is not the same as community-managed. Of course SO is community-*driven*; without the community there would not be a product or a site; it takes humans to ask questions and answer them (so far...)

Comment: -|-1 because this is awesome!!! :D

Answer (score 3):

This 'Answer' isn't directly relevant to the original Question, but is to the subsequent conversation.

There are comments from others who are adamant that a large proportion of S.O. users are discussing upset about the inability to `+1`/`-1` at the beginning of a comment.

I realized that since all discussion is recorded, *"Hey, we have the technology to test that theory!"*  This absolutely isn't meant as a stab at anyone, mostly I was curious, and, yes, I'm so much of a data geek that I just happily spent an hour throwing some stats together.

---

**For the purpose of these stats:**

- *`Users`* are users who have activity since January 1, 2017.
- In regards to this "issue", a *`mention`* is any time one of  {"vote","Vote","+1","-1"} appeared in the User's `Post.Body` or `Comments.Text` during the same period.
- There are many variables that I didn't take into account. This is not factual, just a rough overview, so don't freak out on me.

---

```
    Number of times voting was "mentioned":     13,497
     Number of users who "mentioned" votes:       1485

                    % of all SO.Meta users:       0.3%    [3 of every 1000 users]
                         % of all SO users:      0.04%   [4 of every 10000 users]

               Number of users who did...        Count      % of Total    Avg Rep     Top
                ...11% of the "mentioning":          2        0.00005%     173958   0.005%
                ...33% of the "mentioning":         32         0.0008%     123047   0.009%
                ...50% of the "mentioning":         78          0.002%      62552    0.03%

           Users who DIDN'T mention it...        Count      % of Total
               Stack Overflow - Meta Users:    496,612           99.7%
                      Stack Overflow Users:  4,136,728         99.964%
```

My interpretation of this is that 78 users are equally concerned about this issue as are the other 4,000,000+ users combined.  On the other hand, those are also some of the site's top users by reputation.

...so `+1` to all!

Comment: "plusoned" for the data. (And now you have another pattern to search for.) I can't linguistically parse your second paragraph/sentence. Can you rewrite it so that I know what you mean?