# Make "+1" and "-1" comment blocks a warning instead

Tags: feature-request, comments, content-blocklist

Today I was trying to comment on a post about negative indexing and I ran into this:

[image]

I thought this was pretty ridiculous. If I suddenly felt a desire to explain to a user that their post was garbage there are plenty of better and more colorful words that I can choose from that are far more effective than "-1".

On the flip side, for a case like the one above, this block accomplishes nothing except being annoying. Especially, when it tells me to not comment on my downvote when I didn't downvote.

After seeing [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283874/remove-the-limitation-that-stops-comments-from-starting-with-1-or-1) from four years ago, it feels like the block is here to stay. If it is absolutely necessary to keep this in place, please make it a warning and give the user the option to continue anyway. In situations like these I think the user is a better judge of what kind of comment should be posted than something that checks the first two characters.

Comment: You probably could get around that by adding backticks to that, or by rearranging your sentence...

Comment: @Makoto Right but the same can be said for anybody who wants to bypass it for negative purposes, so why is it here?

Comment: If comments had warnings, I'd have done that years ago. But they don't.

Comment: @Primusa - It's educational. If you don't know that you're not supposed to leave comments like +1, this will let you know. On a different note, the comment you're trying to leave doesn't look like it fits the purposes of a comment either; it looks more suited to be an answer than a comment.

Comment: This specific case could be easily solved by using the The article.

Comment: Technically, this can be bypassed relatively easily with any wording changes. It doesn't block -1 anywhere IIRC, just at the start