# On Stack Overflow, would flagging a bunch of un-needed comments found via SEDE be helpful?

Tags: support, moderation, comment-flags, thanks, no-longer-needed

This is a follow-up from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374826/is-flagging-a-bunch-of-thanks-comments-ok). Tl;dr:

> Q: Is flagging and removing manually a bunch of unneeded thank-you comments as found by [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1537634/comments-saying-thanks-to-a-user) OK?
>
> A: Generally, but make sure it makes sense for that site, and that the mods don't mind. [Mithical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/u/294691/) also suggested that I clean up any posts that need cleanup along the way.

I was also cautioned to check with the moderators, as not all sites want that, and that flagging tons of comments (daily flag limit of 100) might be unexpected for smaller sites.

So, would me going around and flagging (manually) a bunch of "thank you" comments and other *No Longer Needed* comments that my script found (of course, also flagging any "you're welcome" or similar) be ok on the Stack Overflow specifically?

[This Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) question makes me think it's fine, but I wanted to double check first.

The suggested duplicate ([Flagging a whole comment thread as obsolete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254853/flagging-a-whole-comment-thread-as-obsolete)) recommends using custom moderator flag to clean up whole threads of comments, but it feels that custom flag would be even more work for moderators compared to regular NLN flags and does not seem to address whether flagging in semi-automated way (instead of natural search) is acceptable.

The (second) [suggested duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283030/96-wrongly-declined-comment-flags-in-1-day) does not cover *Thank You* comments. It is about a different type of comment, so I don't feel it is applicable here. [This other Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276791/can-i-flag-posts-from-sede-or-a-search-in-bulk-if-theyre-low-quality) is about suggested link comments, which is a different type of comment again. So please make sure the duplicate is applicable to this type of comment.

Comment: Also [What is the correct procedure for handling large amounts of trashy comments on a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322702/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-handling-large-amounts-of-trashy-comments-on-a)

Comment: Absolutely, flag away. If mods are overwhelmed with flags, there are things that can be done to resolve that. We shouldn't be limiting needed curation just to limit the size of the flag queue, if cleanup is needed, it should occur.

Comment: I would personally ask "does it matter"? Sure, I flag comments like that when I find them during my "normal" usage of the site, but I don't actively seek them out. If everyone with the flag privilege simply flagged them as they find them as they used the site normally when we wouldn't have a "problem".

Comment: Also [Can the mods agree on how we should mass-flag comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338911/can-the-mods-agree-on-how-we-should-mass-flag-comments)

Comment: It's good to differentiate between flags that moderators need to handle, and flags that automatically get handled. Removing a bunch of _plz upvote and accept_ comments that are instantly handled because of a keyword is fine imo, pushing a ton of old comments that are irrelevant but harmless in a mod queue isn't imo

Comment: @ErikA Most will probobly get instantly handled, but chances are there will be a few that aren't, like when someone asks for clarification, but they leave the comment after clarification has been added. Is that list of keywords public?

Comment: It is acceptable and it's a good thing to do, but when doing so make sure you are not creating too many low-value flags for moderators. Thank you comments (and ones that beg for acceptance or upvotes) are often removed with a single flag without a need for moderator to review it. You can flag these as much as you want. Don't raise flag on the questions asking to remove comments unless there's a very long off-topic conversation happing in comments.

Comment: The score of '-2' does not mean "you shouldn't". You are reading too much into the score. While votes in meta can be cast to show agreement, they can also be cast to express an opinion on the question's clarity, research evidence, and general usefulness.

Comment: yeah, seconding yivi here - the vote count does not necessarily mean you should not (in fact, I would say - definitely should, any contribution that helps keep SO clean of noise is very welcome). Some negative reception might come from that we all know that mods on SO have a *ton* of flags to deal with. Speaking of the latter, as others mentioned, the comments you speak about in the post will likely be insta-deleted on the first flag or deleted upon reaching the threshold.

Comment: One note-worthy thing, though: if you encounter a post where you want to flag more than a couple of comments (those that are not instantly deleted that is), it is better to mod-flag the whole thread and explain the reasons it needs to go - mods will handle the rest

Comment: @OlegValter That makes sense, thanks! I just got a bit confused because I'm not very active on SO (I mostly focus on Ask Ubuntu), both this question and answer being downvoted confused me a bit at first, and the mixed-messages that I was getting, given that several high-rep users [and even mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374852/1081494) have given me different advice, so I'm going to go ahead and do it, and if anyone tells me to stop (or suspends me), then I can stop.

Comment: @cocomac don't worry about that too much - as long as you maintain discretion and use common sense when flagging, you should be OK. Cleaning up the site is a venerable occupation - in any case, no one is going to suspend you for a bunch of flags (especially those that are helpful), at the very most you will be asked to slow down a little if the drawbacks of such action start to outweigh the benefits. There is, certainly, some difference in views regarding how much discretion is required, but I've always felt the general consensus is in favour of curation rather than against it.

Comment: I think this question deserves separate consideration for "comments found with a script" part. I voted to re-open and edited the post (@cocomac please review/rollback) to reflect that along with why duplicate does not address that part. The second part of the question ("cleanup posts") should be separate question and likely impossible for <2K users due to edit reviews queue being full all the time - so I removed that part, feel free to convert into another question if you need an answer  (make sure to specify <2k condition).

Comment: Folks, there is nothing that the proposed duplicate question answers or helps here. At best, it shows an anecdotal example or mass flagging that was not well received then.

Comment: I am horrified by the stance of the answers on the nominated duplicate page.  I needed to downvote both answers and upvote the question.  This stonewalling of volunteer curators is a smack in the face and will turn away a valuable resource -- people trying to help.

Comment: **DEAR ALL CLOSE VOTERS**: I'm all done trying to keep this question open. I'm going to start (manually) flagging **any and all** comments I believe are no longer needed, regardless of how I found them. If the mods have a problem with that, and they ask me to stop, I will. But unless they ask me to stop, I'm going to try given how many (completely conflicting) answers I've been given. I will post an update if I get asked to stop. I only plan to do this on Stack Overflow. I would appreciate it if someone explains how the dupe is a dupe, given that it refers to link-only comments, not thanks

Comment: Please explain why the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283032/1038015) in the duplicate does not answer your question. You're proposing to create flags based on a SEDE query and that answer covers your case as far as I can see. Note that the accepted answer was written by someone who was a moderator at the time of writing the answer although he's not a moderator any more.

Comment: @RobertLongson That appears to suggest that if current moderators wished to explain how they currently handle mass flagging done with the assistance of SEDE, they would have to answer that question instead of this one, which frankly does not make much sense. Not to mention the loads of other problems with that particular answer when posed against this question. It is based on incorrect assumptions and proposes alternatives which do not really help in contrast with letting curators flag away.

Comment: @RobertLongson The accepted answer there is confusing for several reasons: (1) It's pretty much the opposite of the accepted answer here (2) that OP was asking about people making [legitimate] requests for an answer to be accepted when the OP didn't accept one. Here, I'm asking about flagging "thanks" comments, which I feel are different, and are completely unhelpful - I'm referring to when someone says "thanks" on an answer, or when they are asked to add something to the post, and if they've added it, I'll flag the request and the "Thanks, done" as No Longer Needed, as the info has been added

Comment: Speaking of flag handling, I see Bhargav is one of the close voters - given they used to be *the* flag handler on SO, it would be great to hear their opinion on such flagging and the workload it creates - Bhargav, if you follow this, could you please share your perspective on the matter?

Comment: Well **you** accepted the answer to this question. I can't help it if you accepted the opposite answer to that of a moderator and I don't think that's evidence that what you want to do is OK. It's moderators that will handle your flags so caveat emptor there. 2. That ex-moderator said that they don't want to deal with a flood of SEDE found comments.

Answer (score 9):

This isn't new to some of you, but I flag comments on a weekly basis with assistance from SEDE. The reasons enumerated:

- Although a great deal of problematic comments are detected quickly, primarily thanks to the [Heat Detector](https://stackapps.com/questions/7001/heat-detector-analysing-comments-to-find-heat), this hasn't always been the case, and still today there are false negatives, some bad comments are only found much later.
- Even the Heat Detector is not designed to find comments which sit in this borderline that we may call one of many things: non-constructive, noisy, annoying, ranty. While these things are not necessarily unfriendly or abusive, they are unwanted and should still be flagged.
- And frankly, another problem is that people don't seem to flag enough. Rather than flagging comments, a fair share of our users prefer escalating with more comments instead. So not only are bad comments not removed when they should be, *each heated comment is a seed for a violent discussion*.
- What about *"too many flags already"*? It is <s>a scam invented by flag holders to cast less flags</s> less of a problem than people are picturing it. Flags are still categorized, although at the end a total flag count is displayed regardless of the kind of flag. Moderators also have the [unfriendly bot](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/09/the-unfriendly-robot-automatically-flagging-unwelcoming-comments/) automatically flagging an enormous amount of comments, which can be ignored for as long as there are other flags to handle. The main issue with a high number of flags to handle is that it may feel overwhelming to them. But in the end, having less flags does not mean that there are less problematic comments.
- Finally, why not let them be once they're old? Because they are not excused just because of being old. We literally curate our questions to last, so this should be no different for cleaning up the comments underneath. It is not unheard of for people to call out "the problems with Stack Overflow" by linking a very old question. Moreover, every once in a while there's someone replying to an old comment thread.

Still, if you plan to traverse a specific pattern of comments via SEDE or a similar integration, consider picking up only the ones in the last few days, rather than trying to cover the full history of the site. At that point, that is a bit too much. You wouldn't have enough flags to handle that in a healthy way anyway.

Also, I thought I did not have to mention this, but just to be sure: *do check* each comment that you are flagging, rather than automatically flagging everything captured by the query. That would be where flagging becomes a true hindrance.

Comment: I should note there's an unfriendly comment bot SO runs looking for bad comments as well

Comment: @Machavity That is the bot that I referred to in the fourth point. I edited in a link for clarity.

Comment: Do you rate-limit yourself (e.g., using some kind of queue or similar)? In any case, what would be a reasonable upper limit (if below some system limit)?

Comment: Re *"Finally, why not let them age away?"*: Joel Spolsky mentioned that in the (claimed to be) [episode 400](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/14/podcast-400-an-oral-history-of-stack-overflow-told-by-its-founding-team/) ([direct MP3 link](https://cdn.simplecast.com/audio/6fa1d34c-502b-4abf-bd82-483804006e0b/episodes/cb0b43f3-6472-48a0-bc43-b2c27426fac0/audio/c9f2643c-141e-44bf-a5f5-3a8a0e5c6133/default_tc.mp3)) at 16 min 26 secs. But even that is probably not enough to change it. Perhaps in 6-8 millennia?

Comment: I agree with all of this except for the prioritizing of new comments.  I prefer to promote everyone having their own special sauce/algorithm while curating.  This diversity of attention will have a better chance of find more of the noise.  Half of the reason that I am a necro-answerer on SE sites is because I prefer to take the road less traveled.  Everybody and their neighbour are hanging over top of the new and recently active question pools -- I prefer to improve old content because old content is used to close new content.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I am organically limited by the 100 daily flags. As the new wave of comments arrive on each SEDE database update, which happens weekly, it may take a few days to traverse the list and flag the ones worth flagging. I edited the answer again, by the way, as I wasn't really thinking about a potential comment aging mechanism.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sure, it is natural to see diversity in curation patterns. So long as they haven't called you out (or better, they have told you it's fine and dandy), then this answer does not intend to make a rule of thumb. I suspect that the mass flag decline presented in the linked question was on something that could be so trivially automated that there was no interest in having humans mass flagging them. In my case, there is no regex that can accurately match the patterns.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, this seems fine.

Leaving aside the specifics of this case and speaking in generalities, I worry a little bit about this kind of mass flagging because two things can go wrong:

- the query you craft might be overbroad and catch, for instance, comments that have some valuable content *along with* something like "Thanks" that the query looks for
- a comment that genuinely wasn't valuable when first posted may have *become* valuable if there are now valuable *replies* to it that would be rendered nonsensical by its deletion. This kind of nuance requires a careful look at the full context of the comment to spot, but such time-consuming scrutiny is a nuisance and tempting to skip when flagging en masse.

Manually looking at the comments in context before flagging (as you propose doing) should allow you to spot these cases, though, and the specific SEDE query you link to in the question is pretty conservative and doesn't look at a glance like it's caught any false positives. As such I see no harm in doing what you propose and such cleanup is at least slightly useful, so go ahead!

Comment: cocomac's SEDE query limits the total length of the comment to 20 characters.  You'll have a hard time adding value to a thanks comment in 20 characters or less.

Answer (score -14):

Probably not.

Stack Overflow is the most popular network site by at least two orders of magnitude, and it deals with a large volume of flags.  Suddenly adding more flags to the queue to clean up "unneeded" comments is going to add more burden to that flag queue.

What would be better is if there was something automated that could do it instead, which is what I originally thought you were advocating for.

Comment: FWIW most of the flags caught by the query won't put anything in the flag queue; the system will handle them automatically.